# Are Constructed Languages on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Constructed languages, such as Quenya or Klingon, are a fascinating topic and can be an amazing way to bring a culture to life. We already have a question on the topic:

- [How does one go about developing a language for a particular culture in your world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/19/17)

On the other hand, there is also already a [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) which might be better equipped to answer such questions. While clearly related to worldbuilding, it's a specialized-enough discipline that I'm not sure that *worldbuilding experts* are going to necessarily be experts on it – while *linguistic experts* seem pretty likely to be, or at least give legitimately educated conjecture.

But it's still pretty obviously related. Does Worldbuilding.SE think it can handle constructed languages? When do questions about constructing languages go beyond our purview, into the realm of Linguistics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After looking at the Linguistics meta (especially [this question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/should-we-include-conlangs-in-our-scope)) it is likely that a significant portion of constructed language questions would be deemed off-topic there.

It is not uncommon for two sites to have overlaps (science fiction with movies and TV). The asker is generally encouraged to ask their question on the site that is either most appropriate, or that they believe would give them the most helpful answer.

Comment: I agree. There's a big difference between "what is a dialect" and "what should insect people sound like".

Answer (score 4):

We can certainly suggest appropriate help material (see [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/are-software-recommendation-questions-on-topic) question, it has a slightly different context, but the idea is similar). And as Donald said, we can answer some questions that would be off topic on [Linguistics.SE].

We will probably also have some people that have knowledge in linguistics and are also interested in world building. These people could would be able to answer such questions.

Answer (score 1):

We do not only feel they are on-topic, as part of world-building (remember that Middle Earth started with some poems in constructed languages), but have even discussed about the proper tag [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125/should-questions-about-conlangs-be-tagged-with-conlangs-or-is-linguistics-g)