# Are software recommendation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There are lots of various software packages out there that assist in the creation of a world, from keeping track of details, characters and plots to map creation tools. Are questions asking for recommendations on which software to use for a specific task on topic?

An example question might be:

> What software is available / recommended to help me build the maps for my world?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### I would say "Yes, if specific enough".

Most SE sites don't allow recommendation questions, but there's a whole [Software Recommendation SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) that's specifically for it.  While they're good at finding software over there, it's a fairly low-traffic place and the kind of question which would be asked here is likely to be very specific, with answers talking about little-known software.  We can do a better job of answering **world building software** questions internally than by pointing people over there.

That said, we need guidelines, and I think theirs are worth adopting, at least as a starting point. (See image, [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), and [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality).)

[image: SoftwareRecs.SE question guidelines]

A good question would state what the intended use is (world generation, naming, knowledge maps, etc), what kinds of features it should have (random generation from a seed, word lists, smart linking, etc).  A good answer would address that use and those features and ideally include something of a personal review of the software.

Comment: This. Maybe the [softwarerecs.se] guidelines should be incorporated by reference somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - We should just copy them, then modify appropriately.  We'd have different "bad question" examples, for instance.