# What have we built?

Tags: discussion

As a community we've helped each other construct worlds, build ideas and solve difficult problems.

It's time for a little self promotion to show off what our community has achieved. What have you created?

Comment: I keep reading this title and thinking "We've created a monster..." I've been watching too many films!

Comment: Hahahaha ITS ALLLIVE!  Sorta true actually...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please edit answer and post your success stories

**Liath**

- [Delta Fay and the Lady from Arendal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PEKMXP6) - When Delta is summoned home from her mutually agreed exile and dispatched halfway around the world she wants to know why. But this time she isn't travelling alone, as the young woman is thrown into a foreign conspiracy she must protect not only herself but the person she holds most dear... [@DeltaFay](http://twitter.com/deltafay)

Comment: Would you prefer all the examples to be in one answer? Separate answers would allow voting - would you see that as a good thing?

Comment: My upvote on this meta question indicates that I like the idea of showcasing work from the community. My upvote on this meta answer indicates that I like this particular piece of work. That's why I'd like to see each work in a separate answer.

Comment: @githubphagocyte I'm happy either way I wanted to focus the page more on what we've achieved rather than "hey read my book" so thought a wiki may be the best approach.

Comment: I like the idea of having one community-wiki answer where we collect everything.  There's no need to create competition among the various works.  My upvote on this answer means I like this idea; I haven't yet read the linked work.

Comment: We could possible make different answers for different media, though it does seem weird to have the various media compete with each other...

Comment: I'm keen it doesn't become a competition and I think if we start voting people's work up and down we run that risk. I suggest simply using the same wiki answer and sorting either chronologically or alphabetically. We can always split it out later if we need to. After all, it's just bragging rights!

Comment: Good points Liath and @MonicaCellio - this doesn't need to be a competition. I'm in danger of applying voting to everything...

Comment: That is often the point of SE!