# What platform do we want our blog on?

Tags: discussion, blog

We have one [unofficial blog on WordPress](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/the-blog-up-and-waiting-for-writing). Another unofficial blog on [something called medium](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/medium-blog-contributorsions) is in the works. When we [first started thinking about a blog, Blog Overflow was down](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/worldbuilding-blog-phase-1-and-2-raising-the-idea-and-definition) (the official Stack Exchange blog thingy.) Its [back up](http://stackexchange.com/blogs) and seems to be doing good now.

My question is, where does the community *want* their blog hosted?

Answer (score 4):

Blog Overflow is not available to us.  The site is up but they aren't letting communities create blogs there.  That was the whole point of [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2504/28) -- see the answer there from Abby, who works for SE.

She suggested Medium as a good alternative to the SE-hosted blogs we can't have, and that's why we're pursuing that now.  I'm happy to take advantage of the research SE has already done on this, so while I'd never heard of Medium before this, I say let's go for it.  In addition to getting a blog that SE thinks is technically viable, we can provide feedback to SE for *other* sites who want to do this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best place for a blog is the official platform: http://stackexchange.com/blogs. This is so it would show up with the other community blogs, and it would be more visible. Users also wouldn't have to sign up or use any other websites.

[It also comes with a chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs)

I understand why we would've wanted to roll our own blog when blog overflow was down, but blog overflow is back.