# Want to be interviewed?

Tags: discussion, blog

We've been doing a series of interviews for the [Worldbuilding Community Blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory/latest). And we are looking for volunteers to be interviewed.

Examples can be found below.

It doesn't matter if you're new to Worldbuilding or have been here for ever. If you're up for doing a quick interview just leave a comment here or write a note in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory).

Additionally, if you'd rather interview others, you're also welcome.

Comment: I could do that, sure.

Comment: @CAgrippa I'm going to be in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory most of today, when you're available poke me in there and we'll arrange that interview.

Comment: @CAgrippa if you're still interested in being interviewed, ping bilbo in the chat room (see previous comment).

Answer (score 4):

As it might be interesting to gather all the interviews in one post, here is a list that were published so far.

Note that there is often a delay between an interview and its publication as we work with a publication queue to alternate the type of posts.

#### Users

- [ArtOfCode](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2685/artofcode): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-artofcode-5221953e8748),
- [bowlturner](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19/bowlturner): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-bowlturner-dbde33e9183d#.xehrpevt1),
- [DaaaahWoosh](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6507/daaaahwhoosh): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-daaaahwoosh-1875a52778d0#.dmsnhuaex),
- [dot_Sp0T](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2746/dot-sp0t): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-dot-sp0t-4bf4a1654861#.n2zh6i6sn),
- [Frostfyre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6986/frostfyre): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-frostfyre-ce8ee5071cb7#.z0bx3shot),
- [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-green-7db999b4777a#.uxhoq7ivg),
- [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-hde-226868-3763bc7705aa#.xu5zb4uge),
- [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-james-c693f062d63b#.wek745ho1),
- [Joe Bloggs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9887/joe-bloggs): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-joe-bloggs-91f6a0cf2eec#.2uqp64ua9),
- [Monica Cellio](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/28/monica-cellio): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-monica-cellio-f9a038f999ab#.2czzcn1b3),
- [Samuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3202/samuel): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-samuel-7f0887ad85c#.gf2bxh5e0),
- [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-tim-b-6c05407b4884#.q5n7st4ha),
- [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b): [interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-tres-2b-651a86dadd52#.x1fythqd7).

#### Special

- First elected mod team: [group interview](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-the-moderators-6fe9d7119fd1#.l8vpt6f8a).

#### Coming up

- [Aify](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6453/aify) (completed & queued),
- [Monty Wild](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/75/monty-wild) (completed & queued),
- [Serban Tanasa](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa) (completed & queued)

<sub>*Status as of 2016-05-02*</sub>

Comment: For those of us that don't know, could you add something to indicate in what field of expertise each interviewee is proficient?  I'm sorry that I don't know anything about HDE 22686868.

Comment: @ozone, I'm sorry, but many of them are proficient in many fields. There's a link to both the user profiles an the interview. If you don't know anything about a user, it's a good idea to read their interview. You'll be done in 5 min max for each of them. And how about you? fancy telling us more about yourself?

Comment: I'm an antenna engineer with an interest in cars and writing sci-fi, but I don't feel knowledgeable enough to be interviewed.  I came to meta, looking for a biologist to pick his/her brain about the alien life I created for a book I'm writing.  I'm not sure exactly what 'meta' is.

Comment: @ozone, you are a worldbuilding user, that's enough qualifications to be interviewed. But there's no obligation either :) Meta is meant as a place to ask things about the site, or discuss the site. Or ask things about a question. If you want to try to find someone to discuss, then the [chat] is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @ozone 'meta' means metabolism! Just joking, I have no idea what it means either.