# Is he dead yet?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just did my <s>fourth</s> fifth(? stopped counting...) review on an answer to the question

[You are an advanced AI that controls a smart house. How do you kill your master?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35243/you-are-an-advanced-ai-that-controls-a-smart-house-how-do-you-kill-your-master)

As it stands now, the question has

- a total of <s>29</s> 30 answers,
- <s>17</s> 18 answers with score <= 3,
- <s>five</s> six of those with zero score and (partly) below, and
- About a third of the answers (<s>9</s> 10) are posted by users with <200 reputation.

In light of the [recent discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site/3034#3034) about *what-if type* of questions; this question especially caught my eye, as it keeps attracting more and more answers by new users with questionable quality. I do not intend to start the same discussion within this question, but what I *do* look for is a way to protect this post from more mid-to-low-quality postings, as I feel like the total quality of the question seems to suffer under the increasing amount of answers, and I wonder if we could (should?) do something about it.

It has already been discussed that those questions are somehow off-topic for being idea generation. So, **for this specific question**, should we close it? Protect it? Not to punish the author of a well-recieved question, but to prevent it from getting heavily overloaded.

Comment: I just went to look and Monica's already protected it. Protection is there to handle exactly this scenario :) For the bigger on/off topic discussion...that needs discussion :)

Comment: I try to alert moderators of questions that I think need protection, either with flags or in chat. They can't be everywhere at once and most of them will protect anything that I can show has at least two 1Rep's answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've gone ahead and protected it (thanks for the alert).  This can be easily reversed if we decide later that it's unneeded.

Protection is usually warranted when a question attracts several poor-quality answers from new users.  In fact, a question is automatically protected if three answers from new users are deleted.  In this case none of the answers you're talking about are deleted (and many are at 0 rather than downvoted), so while protecting the question helps reduce *future* answers, the community still needs to address the current answers.  Please (everybody, not just OP) look them over, leave helpful comments, flag low-quality or non-answers for review, vote, and so on.  Please remember that these answers might have been those users' first encounter with our site, so guide them where you can.  Helpful tip: in a comment, "[tour]" is a shorthand for the tour page and "[edit]" is an edit link for that post.

Comment: I did not want to imply that every answer was bad. In fact, some of the answers I reviewed seemed totally fine. I just wasn't sure about wether such a load of answers serves any purpose as I doubt anyone reads every single one of them.

Comment: Right, I'm not trying to say every 0-score answer is bad, either.  I haven't even read them all!  I'm just asking people to take a look, vote (up *or* down!) as appropriate, leave helpful comments, flag the ones that shouldn't be there, etc.  Let's review the answers on this question.

Comment: Alright! Let's do this! :)