# How is "WhatIf" different from Worldbuilding?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There is a [site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95463/what-ifhypotheticals) up for a WhatIf.SE. The first question up is [How is this different from Worldbuilding](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22863)?

I request help crafting an answer to that. I'm not very active here, only read a smattering of questions, and would love the input of more-experienced and more-knowledgeable community members on the matter.

Comment: Note that, since posting this question, [an answer has been provided](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/a/22871) by [ArtOfCode](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2685/artofcode) and commented on by [Tim B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-b). Likely due to this question, so thanks for bringing it to the community's attention.