# We should have a World Building World blog!

Tags: discussion, blog

On [How shall we celebrate our birthday?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/how-shall-we-celebrate-our-birthday), I was reading [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/how-shall-we-celebrate-our-birthday) idea for us post our stories. I was wondering how this would when it hit me!

It has already been discussed [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/worldbuilding-blog-phase-1-and-2-raising-the-idea-and-definition), but it did say "his thread will likely not lead directly to us having our own blog" due to blogs being on hold. I think the birthday would be an excellent time for making the blog!

Here is my proposal. We make a blog for our birthday. Blog posts would be *worlds*, specific settings that could be used in stories. Other elements of the story (characters, plot, conflict, etc...) would be minimal or nonexistient.

We could get a ton of blog posts this way. We would make sure only top quality stuff goes on it, but we would be unlikely to run out of ideas.

Indeed, the blog posts could function as *templates* for worlds used on the main site. For example, if you have a world about a galactic empire, a person on main could link to the blog post to start their question.

What do you think? Is a World-Building World blog a good idea?

Comment: We already have a blog here, I might feature it so that it everyone will be aware of it's existence : http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/the-blog-up-and-waiting-for-writing

Comment: @Vincent I was thinking of a blogoverflow blog.

Comment: Related: [Can we have an SE blog for this site?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2504/29)

Comment: I like the idea of launching a blog for our birthday (the related post above is about *where* to do it and isn't meant to compete with this).  Why restrict content *only* to built-out worlds, though?  Let's be open to all related content and see where it takes us.  Assembling a complete world, and then packaging it in a form that can be consumed by others, is hard -- but we have lots of good material for blog posts, as discussed in previous meta posts.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah. I was just hoping worlds *would* be on topic. It can have other stuff too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You're a diamond person. How do we proceed?

Comment: @PyRulez if you're ok with more general content (and just want to make sure that worlds are included), can we mark this question as a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/487/28)?  That's the original "let's have a blog" post; what's new here is that we want to do it *now*, as part of our birthday, but that probably doesn't need its own question?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, that post wasn't about directly leading blog, but you could probably mark it duplicate.

Comment: Understood -- it's not an exact duplicate.  But in the interests of collecting all the "what should our blog contain?" discussion in one place, I'm going to mark this as a duplicate.  If none of the answers there reflect your suggestion already, please add an answer!  And thanks for bringing this up again and remind us all about the idea -- much appreciated.