# Do we want resource recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

This is based in part on [a chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23718231#23718231) I wrote on Thursday, which I'm now acting on (ignore the linked question).

**Some** sites on Stack Exchange allow, in some form or another, resource recommendations, using one or more of the following tags:

- [resource-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) ([Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations))
- [online-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources) ([Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources))
- . . .

You get the idea.

We currently have the [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) tag (and Stack Exchange also has [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), and [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations) may enter private beta soon), and we have the [worldbuilding-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-resources) tag, so recommending worldbuilding resources works on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. However, I'd like to take it a step further, and suggest that more resource recommendations be on topic, specifically

- [book-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendations)
- [website-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-recommendations) ([Site for online custom map with tags or labels](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4726/site-for-online-custom-map-with-tags-or-labels) is really one of these, not a [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) question; the same goes for [Best platform for collaborative worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/best-platform-for-collaborative-worldbuilding))
- [resource-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) as a catch-all for the rest, if there is anything that doesn't fit in the above two tags, [software-recommendations](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations) or [tag:worldbuilding resources]

As such, I'm working on [a trial question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/what-is-a-good-book-for-developing-a-constructed-language) to test the waters.

Should we have resource recommendation questions? If so, what should the limits be?

The relevant precedent question is [Are software recommendation questions on topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/are-software-recommendation-questions-on-topic); [When are software-recommendation questions on topic?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/563/when-are-software-recommendation-questions-on-topic) is also relevant and based on [Are Wikis the only solution for creating online encyclopedias? [closed]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/are-wikis-the-only-solution-for-creating-online-encyclopedias).

Comment: Mi Yodeya uses a single product-recommendations tag (and considers things like web sites to be in this category).  If we do this I definitely recommend a single something-recommendations tag, not one per type of resource.  Somebody looking for info on a topic might be happy with a book *or* a website *or* a video tutorial *or* whatever; don't fragment on that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've been considering that. If there's a tag called "resource-recommendations", then there's clearly confusion with "worldbuilding-resources". I figured it would be best to push the ideas of the topics first and then have a go at the tags.

Comment: Either tag name would work; the main thing is that if they're talking about the same thing there should only be one.

Comment: It's all the same thing. Let's just keep the most relevant: [tag:worldbuilding-resources] ?

Answer (score 6):

I feel like this is already covered tag wise with the  [worldbuilding-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-resources) tag.

I wholly support asking for resources from people, though lets be honest in most cases answers are going to be opinion based...so I am not sure how this would work.

Questions in this category will need to be very specific.

**Potential good questions:**

*I need a book that illustrates Mayan dress during the height of the empire*

*I need a book that details Roman military organization and tactics prior to the Marian reforms*

Comment: While I don't object to (specific) resource-request questions (there's precedent), if you're tempted to ask a question like that why not recast it to ask for *the answer* instead of *a pointer to the answer*?  Instead of "a book that illustrates Mayan dress...", why not ask "what did Mayan dress look like during..."?  (Assuming that's on-topic, which it might not be.)  Answers are free to recommend resources, but let's try to ask the question instead of the question leading to the question, y'know?

Comment: @MonicaCellio In general I agree/That makes sense.  I would say the one caveat that comes to mind is when a person asking a question KNOWS its going to be a long open ended answer, in that case I think asking for resource, rather than paraphrasing a whole book may be the better of the two options.

Comment: That's fair.  Mostly I just want people to remember to *ask the real questions* here -- if the real question really *is* "what resource?" then fine, but we shouldn't jump there most of the time.