# Are off-site resource requests off topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions, close-reasons

I just saw this: [Any websites with exhaustively long lists of dead planet types?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45608/any-websites-with-exhaustively-long-lists-of-dead-planet-types) on the homepage. Seems like it's​ just asking for a website with a list of x.

I know this sort of question is frowned upon on Stack Overflow because they tend to attract lots of link only answers and there's rarely if ever any one good/useful answer...

So... How does Worldbuilding community feel about requests for off-site resources?

Comment: Its an explicit close reason everywhere else. I'm ever so slightly baffled and will leave it to a mod to deal with ;)

Comment: @Journeyman that's why I asked. I didn't see it as a close reason here and wasn't sure if this community might have a different perspective.

Comment: See also https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2542/19951

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 I would go as far as to say that it is a duplicate. The comments to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/56386/29 have a number of relevant links.

Answer (score 2):

We have a [worldbuilding-resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-resources) tag.

So it's *different*, but kept separate, and we seem to like it OK.