# Medium Blog - Contribut(ors|ions)

Tags: discussion, blog

I'm in the process of moving our current blog over to a new platform ([Medium](https://medium.com/help-center/publications-d23372baede0)), as part of our birthday celebrations.

Now let's face it. Our old blog didn't *really* get off the ground. Part of the reason for that was because of the entry barrier to the platform (Wordpress), requiring Yet Another Login Credential. Part of the reason was that we didn't have enough people committed to writing things.

So, with a fresh platform let's have a fresh start. I'm now looking for two sets of people:

1. **Contributors**
   We need people who are willing to write for us. It doesn't have to be much - maybe an article a month if we have enough people - but this is the essential bit of a successful blog.
2. **Editors**
   OK, more like *curators*. These people - called "editors" by Medium - are people who are willing to help *me* out with administration. I can't keep a whole blog running by myself! I don't entirely know what this role entails, but it won't be a massive commitment.

There is a community wiki answer below. If you're interested, please add yourself to the relevant section, along with any other detail you want to be known.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/487/28) and [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/524/28) for past ideas about content, and [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2490/28) for some shorter-term ideas to celebrate our birthday.

Comment: I want to volunteer, but since I volunteered to contribute last time and still haven't, I'm going to refrain from making any promises this time around.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh maybe see if anything on [the birthday post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2490/28) inspires you?  You can contribute one thing without committing to contribute on a regular basis.  I hope that many of our blog posts will be one-shots like that.

Comment: Because [Blog Overflow is not available for individual communities](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2507/28).

Comment: We should have a meta post, where we could post blog posts and blog fragments. I have some ideas, but I would want to flesh them out over time.

Comment: @PyRulez That's not something that meta is appropriate for. Use Google Docs or similar

Comment: @ArtOfCode We have a question sandbox. Why not a blog sandbox? I think I've seen other sites do that.

Comment: @PyRulez It's appropriate *if it's a BlogOverflow blog*. Ours is not, is hosted on a different site, is separate. Also, sandboxes are really an outlier exception to the norm: they *don't* fit Q&A fomat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## I'm interested in...

#### Writing/contributing, either on a one-time basis or more frequently:

- ✓ Monica Cellio  (heavier on [writing/presentation/etc](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2061/28) and probably some fiction; probably some "what I learned from the WB community" stuff; light on science)
- ✓ HDE 226868 (mostly harder science articles, but also focused on applying these principles to a world, not simply working on calculations; an astronomy/physics focus, if needed)
- ✓ James ...I wanted to support last time and didn't get around to it, hopefully Ill get more motivated this time around.  I like the process discussions and tips and tricks for making a logically consistent world.
- ✓ Samuel (How to make science and engineering plausible (anti-scoff tips), the mysteries (and non-mysteries) of electricity, how to do research like a grad student, etc.)
- ✓ Vulcronos - Fantasy and building consistant worlds with magic.
- ✓ knave - Conlangs for those like myself with no linguistic background. This would probably be a multi-part series, covering grammar, coming up with vocabulary, and how to make it less like English, and using my own conlang as an example. Also willing to share my world if that's something we'll be using it for.
- ✓ Serban Tanasa. [Here are a few ideas](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/524/worldbuilding-blog-specific-article-ideas/2081#2081), feel free to grab some of them if they haven't been covered yet... Might post ongoing short stories if I get around to polishing a bit.
- ✓ JDługosz (John Długosz). I have an interest in having Hard SF and not-stupid-SyFy-move SF "track" increased knowledge of science *and of the readers*.  In fact, expanding on that with explaination and examples would be a perfect first post.  I'm an experienced (non-fiction) writer and technical editor/contributing editor from the bygone days of dead-tree curated article collections.
- ✓ Mikey (Mikey Lynch) - I am interested in City Building, as I was quite literally building entire cities in Abu Dhabi, and have studied the history (even pre-medieval), economics, law, etc. of settlement and urban planning in my masters.  Would I be restricted to that 'tag,' though?
- ✓ PyRulez - Hard SciFi mostly, maybe some magic, probably only occasionally.
- ✓ Tim B - Will write something occasionally, probably not regularly though.
- ✓ Thales Pereira - People-oriented city building, fantasy realms and large-scale world building. Focus on smart use of magic interwined with technology. I'm also inclined to write articles in the sense of "How Stuff Work", trying to explain the physiology and habits of fantastic creatures in a "encyclopedic" way. I'll post once in a while.

#### Editing/curating:

- ✓ Monica Cellio
- ✓ HDE 226868
- ✓ James
- ✓ bilbo_pingouin
- Serban Tanasa
- Samuel
- JDługosz (John Długosz)
- We've got enough editors for now. Feel free to add yourself here, but we may not need any new blood for a while.

<sub>Ticks indicate a user has been added to the blog's contributor list.</sub>

Comment: @Mikey (I don't know if this will ping you): no, you're not restricted to any particular tag or topic.  I'd love to see some blog posts on city-building, an area so far not represented in the blog at all.  But you're not locked into that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Info: yes, that should have pinged him. I believe editors are eligible for pings.

Comment: @MonicaCellio it managed to ping me.  Yes, I'd be happy to contribute regularly, and my area of expertise (?) is city building and design from the past to the present, and area of interest is in the future.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's too late to add me on this? I would love to join the blog efforts!

Comment: @ThalesPereira it's never too late to add another writer!  Go ahead and add yourself to the list, and then create a Medium account (you can just log in with Twitter/Facebook/Gmail to do so) and tell us what your username is so you can be added to the access list.  There's a [chat room dedicated to the blog](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/27736/universe-factory); please drop in when you get a chance and say hi.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oh, thank you! I'll do both things later tonight!