# How should we implement "share a glimpse into your world" week?

Tags: discussion

Okay, so a lot people would like a ["share a glimpse into your world" week](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2495/8914). My question is, how should we implement this.

The first thought that comes to mind is the [blog we're planning](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/medium-blog-contributorsions). The only problem is that everyone would who contributed would have to become an official medium contributor, even if it's just a one-off thing. This wouldn't be too much of a problem. The best ones would probably be posted to the blog.

So, where should we have people post and write their stories. Should we write them directly on Medium, or prepare them somewhere else for to be more inclusive?

Answer (score 8):

I'm starting this answer, and marking it Community Wiki, to collect links to whatever people want to share from their worlds -- stories, descriptions, game modules, fact sheets, etc.  Wherever you've posted it, please add a link and your name here once you do.  This should make it easier to compile a blog post about it later.  (*Hint: We can only compile a meaningful round-up post if there are multiple submissions.*)

---

Glimpses into people's worlds:

- From the [community blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory) (by author's names):

  - [Artificial Stupidity, chapter I](https://medium.com/universe-factory/artificial-stupidity-5988077490ec) and [notes](https://medium.com/universe-factory/artificial-stupidity-behind-the-story-fc5013a627ea#.j8ur27bud): ArtOfCode's short story for the blog on artificial intelligence,
  - [Cognitive Load](https://medium.com/universe-factory/cognitive-load-6181f84e78c2#.kfzxwlsg8): a short story by ArtOfCode,
  - [Father Simon](https://medium.com/universe-factory/father-simon-e369c4eb2d55#.cga7eodgp): a short story into the world of bilbo_pingouin,
  - [Cateye](https://medium.com/universe-factory/cateye-94fb2dad390f#.3psd3rmam): a short story by Frostfyre,
  - *Coming of Age*: [chapter 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/coming-of-age-chapter-1-63377ccbac4c#.p6gn6q7sw), [chapter 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/coming-of-age-chapter-2-59141b5a3edc#.9n2gn8f78): a story by HDE 226868 based on a question on WB,
  - [The Lost Builder](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-lost-builder-355cf7de7ec6#.prl8hyhvg): a story by Joe Bloggs, inspired by the design of the site,
  - *Sisters*: [chapter 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-a718622d808f), [chapter 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-43c4dccd1bd1), [chapter 3](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-3-3bfaa22068b4), [chapter 4](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-4-e1357240d1c3#.oe9fnu9rj), [chapter 5](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-5-with-commentary-518cd2f51dbe#.5jfzpblpu), [chapter 6](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-6-with-author-notes-a2e8662228bf#.5ziit5bfe), [process notes](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-the-story-behind-the-story-12944abf0d2a): Monica Cellio's polytheists with competing moon gods,
  - [Ash (part 1)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/ash-part-first-418e872c4e04): Green's story based on an answer here,
  - [Decoherence](https://medium.com/universe-factory/decoherence-969205285e4c#.il3r5ky5v), [Red Stranger](https://medium.com/universe-factory/red-stranger-8ab78489795f#.cpoyrj1kp), [Electronic Angel](https://medium.com/universe-factory/electronic-angel-679039cb7381#.6xcpeyily): a series of 3 short stories by Tim B,
  - [Where will Will Hicks](https://medium.com/universe-factory/where-is-will-hicks-1605c08779a9#.x5lkoguh1) and [notes](https://medium.com/universe-factory/deconstructing-will-hicks-554b966960e5#.a823xzru7): a short story of Tim B,
  - [Nature's Oven](https://medium.com/universe-factory/nature-s-oven-eea4c8d197ad#.1j2rvjl9u): a short story by Tim B based on a some WB posts,
- In other support

Comment: Oh, the blog is up. Cool!

Comment: Yup!  Just a few days ago and still getting set up -- we wanted to have some stuff already in place by the time our birthday hits.  Also, the name could change depending on the results of the naming question.  But if you're interested in writing for it, please let somebody know (comment here, ask in chat, whatever).

Comment: I haven't read all your post on the blog but i would really like if you could also include an introduction to your universe and how it's related to WB SE. Including for example, the question that inspired you in writing the story and what some basic informations about the world itself. .

Comment: @Vincent I'm actually working on the "behind the scenes, i.e. how WB helped me with this" post now. :-)

Comment: It was high time to update that list. Hopefully, I haven't left anyone down. If so, this is a community wiki :D

Answer (score 6):

My opinion:  Those who want to post them on our blog should post them on our blog.  Those who want to post them elsewhere (like on their own blogs) and avoid signing up on Medium should do so.  And to bring it all together we should use meta to collect all the parts so we can write a "round-up" blog post.

(*Psst*: Creating an account on Medium is as easy as signing in with your Google, Facebook, or Twitter ID, same as here on Stack Exchange.  You don't need to create a separate login ID and password.)

Comment: It may be too many posts for the blog though, potentially.

Comment: We should have such problems. :-)  I don't think we're likely to overwhelm the blog, and even if there were a lot of individual posts for this, the round-up post that collects links to the rest (a) would be posted last (so at the top) and (b) could be featured.  (If you look around on Medium you'll see that blogs can feature certain posts, giving them prominent placement compared to the others.)

Comment: Fortunately for those who don't have accounts on Facebook, Google or Twitter, there's also the email login option.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on the site (in meta).  Work it like the sandbox - a single question explaining the concept, with "answers" containing the shared content.  Update the question to have a list of links with short descriptions.

That keeps it on-site, it has familiar controls/editting and allows voting (for what that's worth).

This might be insufficient exposure vs the blog option, I just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: This is easy for people who don't care where they post (they're already here, after all), but some people might not want to release their work under a CC license so we have to assume that some links will be off-site.

Comment: This would work if answers were an excerpt and then a link rather than the full post.