# Could we get some prominent blog promotion on our site?

Tags: support, feature-request, blog, site-promotion

[We have a blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2590/28), and it's off to a [great start](https://medium.com/universe-factory).  In its first week and a half or so it's produced eight posts by four different authors, and tomorrow will see a fifth author's first contribution.  There's an active chat room where planning happens, so I know more is coming.

Not bad for something that we've, thus far, promoted only on meta and in chat!  Imagine the readers and contributors we could attract with a little more visibility.

If we were a graduated site we could have a community ad for our blog, like this:

[image: EL&U ad]

Another site is using an ad to promote a community publication project (a book):

[image: Mi Yodeya ad]

Beta sites don't get ads normally.  One beta site has a notice that's important for their community to see all the time (even more than a blog ad), and they did this:

[image: Health notice]

**May we please have some means to promote our blog on the front page?** Right now we're doing that with a featured post in the community bulletin, but [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) isn't forever, nor is it meant to be.

I think a community ad would be more appropriate than a pinned notice; there's already a space where ads go, and the blog, while important, isn't as *essential* as that notice on Health.  But I don't know if there's a technical barrier to a beta site having community ads, while we've seen that there is no such barrier for a notice.

**Ideally**, we'd like a community ad that could go into the rotation with the other site-promotion ads that show up on the front page.  If we can't have that, could we have some other way to promote the blog long-term on main?

Comment: Use [meta-tag:featured] for each new blog post.

Comment: It's worth noting (for whatever SE team member this falls to) that Medium provides an embed code for blogs, which looks like this: `<script async src="https://static.medium.com/embed.js"></script><a class="m-collection" href="https://medium.com/universe-factory">Universe Factory</a>`.

Comment: @PyRulez that would be overkill.  The "featured" tag should feature *site* stuff; this is why I'm asking for a more-general blog ad.

Comment: Response from SE: this is [meta-tag:status-planned].

Comment: @ArtOfCode where did you learn this?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I poked Abby in TL, we exchanged a couple of emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With our [graduation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2767/28) comes the ability to run ads that we design on our site.  These are called community-promotion ads.  Early next year SE will open a post where we can submit designs for ads, and any ad that gets enough votes will join the rotation.

So that people can start thinking about ads (not just this one, but any others we'd like to see), here is the required format for ad submissions:

> **Image requirements**
>   The image that you create must be **300** x 250 pixels
>   Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
>   Must be GIF or PNG No animated GIFs
>   Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

The size requirement is changing for 2016 and beyond; ads will now be 300x250, not 220x250.