# Congratulations, Worldbuilding is graduating!

Tags: discussion, graduation

It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Worldbuilding met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

Your site actually passed this threshold a few weeks ago, but we experienced a number of issues with the first wave of design independent graduations. We've since resolved these, so I'm happy to announce that we're ready to flip the switch for you.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - there is some backlog here as the elections for some of the first-wave sites have also had to be delayed. Elections for you and the other sites in this wave will start being scheduled in December.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. We're very close to the new year and the new ad cycle, and we have some exciting changes planned for these as well. These, too, will begin in December or early January so that you may enjoy the new changes.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Very great news! Thanks for bringing it and for your trust in our community!

Comment: Whoa, awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic.  Anyone know what the record for least amount of time in beta is?

Comment: @James According to [this on the Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252439/whats-the-shortest-time-for-a-completed-stackegg), 223 days for Sustainable Living.

Comment: Did anyone read the first comment under the Christianity answer?

Comment: @Frostfyre that was for a game (StackEgg), not an actual beta.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Didn't know what that was, so I made a guess. Best thing I could find, though...

Comment: @James So good.

Comment: Huzzah! Thank you Stack Exchange gods! Or was it mods?

Comment: What does "design independent" refer to?

Comment: @JDługosz: it refers to the fact that the backgrounds, fonts, color schemes etc. on beta sites are all the same. Previously, part of graduating a site from Beta was changing it to have a unique, site-specific graphic design. But now there's a process for graduating a site before the new design is created.

Comment: @James The original Stack Exchange 2.0 launch, betas only lasted 90 days, so most of the early sites (Web Apps, Arqade, Webmasters, Mathematics...) all only had 90 days of beta before graduating.

Comment: Wahoo! *Starts inventing fictional drinks to celebrate*

Comment: This may have just made my day, though I did also just find out how to display special characters correctly in a CSV file. Anyway, whoo, but do we get any input on the new site design? I'd really like something that looks at least somewhat professional.

Comment: @Daaaah When our designers start working on a site design, they'll be coming to the Meta site here and pitching it to you folks to work on details and get feedback on their proposal.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh the SE design folks have a great track record of professional, high-quality designs.  I'm not worried about that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm not saying it won't look good, I'm just saying I don't want [dragon-fighting cyborgs](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/) or [space angels](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/). Mostly because I browse this site at work and like to look like I'm staying on task, but also because I want this site to feel more serious than most people think we are.

Comment: Awesome! This is fantastic news; thank you for the support you've given us since day one.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the change.  Very exciting!

Comment: Cheers and upvotes for all!

Comment: We should have javascript fireworks or something on this post :)

Comment: It's unclear to me the implications of what community ads are. Does the community somehow benefit financially from them? What exactly will a staff re-design accomplish?

Comment: @corporeal Community Promotion Ads are a [thread like this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/community-promotion-ads-2015), which is basically a way for the community to provide access to the readers of their site to tools, sites, or other such'n's that are relevant but external to your community. No, the community doesn't benefit financially. We do have paid advertising elsewhere on the network, but since the display system is the same for all of our ads, any such change becomes universal.

Comment: Thanks to all the hard work from the people that made this possible.  I've certainly benefited from other SE sites as well, but enjoyed this the most.   Thanks!

Comment: honestly i want to see customized labels and graphics for this site

Comment: Congrats, everyone!

Comment: "In this story, a collection of heros must choose the design of their Multiverse. The multiverse evolved from a fledgling beta site to a giant cool place and it must be redesigned in order for the heros to (enter heroic deed here:_______). How, chosen ones, will you have your site redesigned?" Thanks, lords of the Stack, for all the great support thus far :-)

Comment: I've wanted to be a moderator here like I am on Wikipedia for a while.

Comment: Good to see we get an Icon and stuff!

Comment: @RileySantos Well I'm sure there will be moderator elections at some point fairly soon but I expect they'll have some strong competition for the role. You can get 90% of the moderator powers just by having enough reputation though so enough questions and answers will get you rolling :)

Answer (score 21):

### Congratulations Everyone

I've been on and off this site since private beta, and it's a really cool site. Great job on achieving graduation and creating such good content. Worldbuilding is still my favourite StackExchange site and has some of the most interesting questions on the network! (In my humble opinion).

I'm looking forward to seeing where this goes from here!

Comment: Here's to hoping that everyone keeps up the good work they (*you all*) have been doing so far!