# How will the privilege requirements change, once phase two of the graduation takes place?

Tags: support, graduation, privileges

[Worldbuilding has graduated!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/congratulations-worldbuilding-is-graduating) That's is awesome, and resulted in some changes, like voting for our moderators some time ago.

However,

> The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege.

With the new design coming soon (hopefully), the reputation needed for each privilege will change. What I am curious about, is how exactly these changes will look like.

I compared the [thresholds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) with the ones [over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), but they differed not only in the amount of rep needed, but in the order in which they are achieved as well. What I want to know now is:

*How much reputation will be needed for each privilege?*

I understand, that a privilege should be harder to get, as the community grows, but why for example does it take half as much rep (500) to cast close votes, compared to creation of gallery chatrooms (1000), when it takes triple the amount over at StackOverflow (3000/1000)?

*Will the order stay the same or change? Either way, why the difference?*

Comment: The way I understand it (and this is supported by comparing SO with SFF), there are beta sites and there are graduated sites, and there are different privilege levels for each. So once we fully graduate, privilege levels will be the same as they are on SO.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Yes, this is my understanding as well. However, this does not explain why one would change the order of the privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow has some special settings due to its volume.  The privilege levels are the same on all *other* graduated sites, as [described on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/162102).  There's a table there showing the reputation requirements for each privilege on private betas, public betas, graduated sites, and SO.

Comment: I did not know about that table! Very useful

Comment: I knew about it but was having trouble finding it because I was searching for "privilege" not "reputation".  There's a lot of useful stuff on MSE, but the indexing can be challenging. :-)

Comment: That is very true! Finding the things you look for can sometimes be quite a task

Comment: Small followup for understanding: Within the table it says "Review chat flags 10000 global reputation*   10000" Does that mean as soon as I have an overall total reputation of 10k I get this privilege?

Comment: @T3H40 yes, chat counts your reputation across all sites on that server.  SO and MSE have their own servers, so your rep from those sites doesn't count on the server used by all the other sites, but your rep on Worldbuilding, RPG, SFF, Lifehacks, etc all count toward that 10k requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct, our thresholds will become the same as other graduated sites.

The thresholds here are set to be appropriate for a new site starting out to allow people to get the site up and running. This is very different from those needed to run an already established site.

For example everyone needs to be able to create tags or no-one can ask any questions!

Comment: Tag creation is 1 rep only on private betas. It is bumped to 150 once a site enters public beta. Compare [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).