# Editor's Picks: January 2016

Tags: discussion, blog

As you may know, [we have a blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2590/2685). As part of writing for that blog, I'm going to be writing an Editor's Picks series - essentially a round-up of some of the great stuff we get on this site.

To do that, I need to find some great stuff to write about. Now, while I could do that on my own, it'd be far more effective to ask everyone to nominate something.

So that's why I'm here. For each Editor's Picks post I do (about every month, give or take a week or so), I'll post here on meta, asking for submissions for inclusion. Occasionally, there might be some special criterion (such as questions or answers in one particular tag).

For January 2016, I'm looking for some of the best stuff you've found on Worldbuilding to write about. To nominate a post, please drop an answer on this question linking to the post and giving a (brief, it doesn't have to be long - I'll flesh it out) summary of what you liked about it.

Comment: Can we nominate our own posts?

Comment: @fi12 Sure, go ahead

Comment: Does it have to have originated in Jan 2016?

Comment: @SerbanTanasa For this one, no.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to nominate [Building a bridge to the stars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/34279/328) by [Whelkaholism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9796/whelkaholism).

I like it because the idea seems ridiculous at first and your (or at least my) first thought is: "That will never work!". But after some brief calculating, the concept actually holds up surprisingly well.

Bonus points were also earned for a new form of Handwavium namely: lalalaicanthearyouium.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to nominate [What sort of problem would drive a near omnipotent civilization to seek an “outside the box” solution?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34157/what-sort-of-problem-would-drive-a-near-omnipotent-civilization-to-seek-an-outs). The question itself didn't stand out a lot to me, but the *answers* are fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to nominate the lava questions.

First mine, asked on first January: [Castle surrounded by lava](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/32467/2071)

And second this one asked on 15th: [How would a city styled like Venice be built with lava instead of water?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/33450/2071)

Because: Buildings on lava look cool and both questions and answers show, that living there is not so cool