# Editor's Picks: February 2016

Tags: discussion, blog

As you may know, [we have a blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2590/2685). As part of writing for that blog, I'm writing an Editor's Picks series - essentially a round-up of some of the great stuff we get on this site.

To do that, I need to find some great stuff to write about. Now, while I could do that on my own, it'd be far more effective to ask everyone to nominate something.

So that's why I'm here. For each Editor's Picks post I do (about every month, give or take a week or so), I'll post here on meta, asking for submissions for inclusion. Occasionally, there might be some special criterion (such as questions or answers in one particular tag).

For February 2016, I'm looking for some of the best stuff you've found on Worldbuilding to write about. To nominate a post, please drop an answer on this question linking to the post and giving a (brief, it doesn't have to be long - I'll flesh it out) summary of what you liked about it. It should have been posted in the month of February 2016.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the current scope discussions in meta?

Comment: @TimB Debatable. I'm envisioning EP posts as more reviews of worldbuilding content, rather than meta-posts about the site - but possibly.

Comment: Yeah that's why it's a comment and "might" not an answer. :) Just putting it out there as an option.

Answer (score 1):

[Is there a way to create a bomb to destroy a star?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-bomb-to-destroy-a-star)

Come on, you're blowing up stars! Who doesn't like that? On a more serious note however, this question sparked some really interesting discussion and I enjoyed seeing it unfold. This question could hold some historical significance in the future because it is easily relatable to almost any space-based science fiction novel or short story. The answers also introduced some out of the box ideas ranging from infusing the star with energy to dropping degenerate white dwarf in it.

Answer (score 0):

(Shameless self-promotion ahead.)

[Why fill a dungeon with puzzles?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36446/why-fill-a-dungeon-with-puzzles)

Because it was the [highest-upvoted question in February](http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuildingme/query/447261/questions-asked-in-previous-month) that is still open, [terrified](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36446/why-fill-a-dungeon-with-puzzles#comment101192_36446) several people, sparked numerous humorous comments, and helps form the foundation for why the ruins of a world are the way they are.