# New blog post: With My Conlang, I Would Not Fail (previous: Salvage - Part 2 of Landed)

Tags: discussion, blog

Welcome to the newest post on [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory), the blog of the Worldbuilding community:

**[With My Conlang, I Would Not Fail](https://medium.com/universe-factory/with-my-conlang-i-would-not-fail-f7fbf7990563), by Sean F. Larson**

> In all the talking and back and forth talk, my principal said something. Thinking about it now, I am sure that it was just an off-hand comment. But he said, "He is going to have to invent his own language to graduate from high school." and the light bulb went off.

> Invent my own language? YES! I'm going to invent my own language! I had no idea anyone had ever done this before. I had taken French, and I understood grammar, but I really had no idea how to create an entire language from scratch.

Tags: Constructed languages

---

Previous post: **[Salvage - Part 2 of Landed](https://medium.com/universe-factory/salvage-part-two-of-landed-689363aa2546), by Topcode**

> They went to homebase and unpacked and set up a tent. as they stepped outside they heard a bang. It was an escape pod that had launched and was quickly destabilizing. It was pulling up but not in time. A loud crash sounded as it smashed into the shore, then skidded around before rolling down the slope… and into the water. Fortunately for whoever was inside the flotation activated and kept it from sinking.

Tags: Fiction, Science Fiction

---

There's are currently no stories in the backlog. Want to add one? Check out 
[We have a blog!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2590/28789) and the chat room [Universe Factory](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory).

Would you like to contribute to the blog?  We welcome fiction, science articles, reviews, discussions of worldbuilding process/techniques, case studies... anything that fits in with building worlds!

*We will update this meta post for each new blog post as it's published.  See the answers for a complete list of past blog posts.*

*[Want to Contribute?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/want-to-contribute-b37191c4362e#.o7009o2l6)*

Comment: How can we upvote that dude's work. Its excellent.

Comment: @kingledion authors thrive on comments, and I encourage you to leave him some on his posts.  If you don't have a Medium account already, you can log in with Google, Facebook, or Twitter (like you do here on SE).  I'm sure he'd welcome feedback!  And yes, I agree that Jasper's work is excellent.  (Tease: there's more coming.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Do upvotes carry between blog post updates (have 24 accumulated over time or are they all from this one?) I'd ask elsewhere but we have no meta-meta-worldbuilding.

Comment: @Zxyrra they accumulate over time.  Instead of creating a bunch of individual meta posts, which would get out of hand, we're editing this post with each new blog post.  Votes probably shouldn't be interpreted as votes on the specific blog posts.  (If you want to know how those votes have changed over time, you could use the data explorer.  But that won't tell you if that's why people are voting on this meta post.)

Comment: @Zxyrra You reminded me of this [meta xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1447/)

Comment: awesome work, great to read :)

Comment: Hopefull I might resume and finish the later part of story that I started https://medium.com/universe-factory/transcendence-to-new-world-e19560077f74. I think it's archived, am I too late?

Comment: @KaranDesai great!  It's still there, ready for you to pick it up and continue when you're ready.  I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll submit draft asap on Medium

Comment: I like the *Dr. Strangelove* reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Previous blog posts

Previously on [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory)...

<sub>[Edit this post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5864/edit)</sub>

### 2021

Febuary:

- [Salvage - Part two of Landed](https://medium.com/universe-factory/salvage-part-two-of-landed-689363aa2546) by Topcode

### 2020

December:

- [Supers: Chapter 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/supers-chapter-1-551590eecdb4) by Firestryke

June:

- [Worldbuilding with stellar grids](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-with-stellar-grids-76652f51b7d9) by HDE 226868

May:

- [You are a flat-earther (Or how I learned to stop worrying and model less)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/you-are-a-flat-earther-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-model-less-b1daae928cca) by Joe Bloggs
- [Arrival - Part One of Landed](https://medium.com/universe-factory/arrival-part-one-of-landed-2c1cf57aa77) by TopCode
- [The Juggernaut - Chapter 10](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-chapter-10-9fc21d3420a9) by Monty Wild

April:

- [Elektrodome](https://medium.com/universe-factory/elektrodrome-69e66b02b084) by Chris Brown

January:

- [A Slither of Hope](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-slither-of-hope-cc7e2d3d139f) by Secespitus

### 2019

September:

- [The Mage's Paradox](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-mages-paradox-9ad0d281a2b4) by Suman Jampala

August:

- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 9](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-chapter-9-fd81e5b4ed68) by Monty Wild

July:

- [What if the Sun was made of helium?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-if-the-sun-was-made-of-helium-f97cbdbdd7a1) by HDE 226868

June:

- [Luna’s Experiments: Vacation](https://medium.com/universe-factory/lunas-experiments-vacation-1cafad203e2e) by Secespitus

May:

- [Fenra’s Awakening](https://medium.com/universe-factory/fenras-awakening-da8e6a90c43) by Secespitus (***Warning! Mature content!***)

April:

- [When Gods Fear](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-gods-fear-134da7d29275) by Joe Bloggs

January:

- [“A Disease of Mythology”: The Importance of Language in Worldbuilding](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-disease-of-mythology-the-importance-of-language-in-worldbuilding-d1a9d1f1e2f4) by heather

### 2018

October:

- [If Neptune Orbited Jupiter](https://medium.com/universe-factory/if-neptune-orbited-jupiter-918ef0e53da0) by HDE 226868
- [Discord (Harmony 2): The Entropy Note](https://medium.com/universe-factory/discord-harmony-2-551c3ea4490f) by FoxElemental

September:

- [Fantastical Evolution: A Perfect, Unreasonable New standard & Alternatives](https://medium.com/universe-factory/fantastical-evolution-d7249ad00e0d) by Suman Jampala

August:

- [Narok Ra Zorda](https://medium.com/universe-factory/narork-ra-zorda-582885ff0616) by gryphon

July:

- [Harmony, 1: The Reaping Note](https://medium.com/universe-factory/harmony-harmony-1-ce64c15c8b88) by FoxElemental
- [Golden Sails, Part 4](https://medium.com/universe-factory/golden-sails-part-4-150b30291123) by gryphon
- [Your Time is Come](https://medium.com/universe-factory/your-time-is-come-8a3fbb695baa) by Chris Brown
- [The Unknown Chapter ½](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-unknown-chapter-%C2%BD-29c8227960df) by Haaruun Ibrow
- [Overdue — Short fiction from Federated Human Space](https://medium.com/universe-factory/overdue-short-fiction-from-federated-human-space-d162c3577674) by Ash
- [A Worldbuilding Checklist](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-worldbuilding-checklist-4c1e88f7d1e6) by FoxElemental

April:

- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 8](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-chapter-8-28fb63147fe5) by Monty Wild
- [Sebiar and the adventurers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sebiar-and-the-adventurers-6ccd8ea7f244) by Secespitus
- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 7](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-chapter-7-7e4e51296a77) by Monty Wild

February:

- [The Changing Now](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-changing-now-47a5c241f5f0) by Joe Bloggs

January:

- [When nature beats you to the punch](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-nature-beats-you-to-the-punch-872d8f71e694) by HDE 226868

### [2017 and earlier](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4038/28)

Comment: Thanks James for helping me defeat the "self-answers can't be pinned by the checkmark" problem.

Answer (score 23):

## Previous blog posts

Previously on [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory)...

### [2018 and later](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5864/28)

### 2017

**December**

- [Golden Sails, Part 3](https://medium.com/universe-factory/golden-sails-part-3-f406acd91e0c) by gryphon
- [Call of the Night Raven](https://medium.com/universe-factory/call-of-the-night-raven-4e6c9091143b) by Secespitus
- [Golden Sails, Part 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/golden-sails-part-2-c20636458280) by gryphon
- [Luna's Experiments: Wolf Nose](https://medium.com/universe-factory/lunas-experiments-wolf-nose-2683790048d) by Secespitus
- [Cuban Missile War (Introduction)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/cuban-missile-war-introduction-d2b7e00c97eb) by Future Historian
- [Golden Sails, Part 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/golden-sails-part-1-38885f9f2796) by gryphon
- [Prudus Explains Magic: A Wizard’s Grimoire](https://medium.com/universe-factory/prudus-explains-magic-a-wizards-grimoire-1da41961e7c3) by Secespitus
- [A Priestess of Sila](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-priestess-of-sila-70852d97cbf7), a Quenaunor story by gryphon

**November**

- [The Ambush Part 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-ambush-part-2-24de4e2ec225) by Secespitus
- [The Juggernaut: Chapter 6](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-chapter-6-17c92a54ca4f) by Monty Wild
- [Digital Character Modelling 3 — Customising the body](https://medium.com/universe-factory/digital-character-modelling-3-customising-the-body-e50bc6931bf2) by Bellerophon
- [Luna’s Experiments: Cat Ears](https://medium.com/universe-factory/lunas-experiments-cat-ears-26d2f01764c) by Secespitus
- [Resurrection of the Dead: Practical Considerations](https://medium.com/universe-factory/resurrection-of-the-dead-practical-considerations-5c65746c3845) by Monica Cellio
- [Prudus Explains Magic: A Wizard's Staff](https://medium.com/universe-factory/prudus-explains-magic-a-wizards-staff-76532a439956) by Secespitus
- [Evolution for World Builders](https://medium.com/universe-factory/evolution-for-world-builders-b222a7214e54) by Joe Bloggs

**October**

- [A Bored God](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-bored-god-9d6bc05611d2) by gryphon
- [The Ambush, Part 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-ambush-part-1-404364696d6f) by Secespitus
- [The Challenger](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-challenger-76879018d2cf) by gryphon
- [Mapmaking Software](https://medium.com/universe-factory/mapmaking-software-65c0318fd3a6) by Vincent
- [Digital Character Modelling 2: Making the Basic Body](https://medium.com/universe-factory/digital-character-modelling-2-making-the-basic-body-94b23b2bbea2) by Bellerophon
- [And Psithyrus beat his time](https://medium.com/universe-factory/and-psithyrus-beat-his-time-eaeb2e64b3ca) by Joe Bloggs

**September**

- [Digital Mapmaking](https://medium.com/universe-factory/digital-mapmaking-1fdd11eaf975) by Vincent
- [Digital Character Modelling — an introduction](https://medium.com/universe-factory/digital-character-modelling-an-introduction-8f1fa4bbcbb9) by Bellerophon
- [Konets](https://medium.com/universe-factory/konets-58ae36bce80c) by Future Historian
- [Of Maps and Men, Part 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/of-maps-and-men-pt-1-bb486cc85e7d) by dot_Sp0T
- [Taking into account quantum encryption (part 2)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/taking-into-account-quantum-encryption-part-2-424a54277996) by Heather

**August**

- [Comically wrong — what can happen when you ignore physics](https://medium.com/universe-factory/comically-wrong-what-can-happen-when-you-ignore-physics-dae805cf457b) by Heather
- [Look Up!](https://medium.com/universe-factory/look-up-4c7779483fe7) by Heather
- [At the End of the Day](https://medium.com/universe-factory/at-the-end-of-the-day-9a4b62023663) by Monica Cellio
- [Boltzmann brains and entropy](https://medium.com/universe-factory/boltzmann-brains-and-entropy-7fd6a652767b) by Heather
- [Building the world of The Juggernaut, Part 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-the-juggernaut-ad8ddbb57938) by Monty Wild

**July**

- [Taking into account quantum encryption (part 1)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/taking-into-account-quantum-encryption-part-1-db86d1f1665a) by Heather
- [That's Not Feudalism](https://medium.com/universe-factory/thats-not-feudalism-b83fc04272e0) by Jasper McChesney
- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 5](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-26073bba4e37) by Monty Wild
- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 4](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-61b50578d07d) by Monty Wild
- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 3](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-c06dbd208f5e) by Monty Wild (mature themes: violence, some sexual content)

**June**

- [Sci-Fi Science: Physics of Impossibru: Walkers in Texas](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-i-walkers-in-texas-f8ddf71a7a7e) by Viharmester Birodalma
- [America’s Space Journey Told Through Photos](https://medium.com/universe-factory/americas-space-journey-told-through-photos-8486782fde42) by Andrew
- [Building the world of Ivanturia](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-ivanturia-b77bccb99fca) by DonyorM
- [How Planet-Hunters Identify Distant Exoplanets](https://medium.com/universe-factory/how-planet-hunters-identify-distant-exoplanets-c1b112a78933) by Andrew

**May**

- [Could Life Evolve on TRAPPIST-1?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/could-life-evolve-on-trappist-1-d03c64f7e829) by Andrew
- [The Rumor Builders](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-rumor-builders-261d7475f4b7) by DonyorM
- [Surfing in a fiery paradise](https://medium.com/universe-factory/surfing-in-a-fiery-paradise-ec4064c7fa99) by Joe Bloggs
- [Building the World of the Juggernaut](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-the-juggernaut-234ceeab6479) by Monty Wild
- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-6a8d8b85b2a9) by Monty Wild

**April**

- [The Weasel Queen](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-weasel-queen-d8eeb8de3c0) by DonyorM
- [The Juggernaut, Chapter 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-juggernaut-da4e64041ba4) by Monty Wild
- [Some Theoretical Considerations to World-Building Methods](https://medium.com/universe-factory/some-theoretical-considerations-to-world-building-methods-7bfafe2870b) by Jasper McChesney
- [A Horror Named Jimmy](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-horror-named-jimmy-1fd07b2cf9be) by Joe Bloggs
- [The Invaded Orchard](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-invaded-orchard-bacdf706b032) by DonyorM
- [Orcs and Six-Shooters](https://medium.com/universe-factory/orcs-and-six-shooters-386184ad336) by Jasper McChesney

**March**

- [Analysing the Brutal and the Travelling](https://medium.com/universe-factory/analysing-the-brutal-and-the-travelling-a0012f91f2fd) by Joe Bloggs
- [Climate Modeling 101](https://medium.com/universe-factory/climate-modeling-101-4544e00a2ff2#.pixubucu8) by Jasper McChesney
- [Kulan of Reolia Part 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/kulan-of-reolia-part-2-995c967fa92e#.v1u0pf3o7) by DonyorM
- [The Trouble with FTL](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-trouble-with-ftl-588cb3a3a03c#.pxr1chfa3) by Joe Bloggs
- [The Travelling Storyteller](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-travelling-storyteller-6e2e9fce0627#.7pobly5z5) by Joe Bloggs
- [The Tools of Battle](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-tools-of-battle-fa5b823a00e0#.1w75fwllv) by PipperChip
- [The Brutal Builder](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-brutal-builder-5fbfbad08c2a#.ijfd5s5pe) by Joe Bloggs

**February**

- [Medieval Warfare — An introduction](https://medium.com/universe-factory/medieval-warfare-an-introduction-bd7f8935bb0c#.70jq95k7j) by Mithrandir24601
- [Kulan of Reolia Part 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/kulan-of-reolia-6b5954f081b8#.u1hyj257l) by DonyorM
- [What Inspired the Geography of Great Lakes Earth?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-inspired-the-geography-of-great-lakes-earth-69b21a7a9bd0#.u05jz8kv7) by John Dailey
- [How Great Lakes Earth ≠ Chaos Theory](https://medium.com/universe-factory/how-great-lakes-earth-chaos-theory-39ec61ae6e18#.wxafbblsf) by John Dailey
- [Borcorieus of Vorca](https://medium.com/universe-factory/borcorieus-of-vorca-a0e0ce84617d#.eqc9c9t6u) by DonyorM
- [Hit Them in the Gaps](https://medium.com/universe-factory/hit-them-in-the-gaps-c0cc05abf91b#.df1s5oq6z) by PipperChip

**January**

- [Analysing the Lost, the Itinerant and the Fractal](https://medium.com/universe-factory/analysing-the-lost-the-itinerant-and-the-fractal-28a0a82f4821#.hc8byevco) by Joe Bloggs
- [The Sisters' War: Part 2 (Chapter 12)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-sisters-war-part-2-chapter-12-a29660baf7a4#.g2wytwz0f) by Monica Cellio
- [Space Pirates, Kessler Syndrome, and Astronaut Layovers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/space-pirates-kessler-syndrome-and-astronaut-layovers-74a27f149f8d#.z2j7f588z) by HDE 226868
- [Generating Continents Procedurally with Distortion Fields](https://medium.com/universe-factory/generating-continents-procedurally-with-distortion-fields-d17dd85d5339#.leh7v8b4c) by Jasper McChesney
- [The Philosophy Behind Great Lakes Earth](https://medium.com/@johndailey/the-philosophy-behind-great-lakes-earth-8f17dd6fb9#.h85fnn92x) by John Dailey
- [The Fractal Now](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-fractal-now-110f24c97a3e#.6ptqmjmf2) by Joe Bloggs
- [Stop Saying Rivers Only Converge](https://medium.com/universe-factory/stop-saying-rivers-only-converge-802182652365#.37rkpow29) by Jasper McChesney
- [Calculating Political Power is Hard!](https://medium.com/universe-factory/calculating-political-power-is-hard-7d15983bff1) by Green

### 2016

- [Fight Earnestly](https://medium.com/universe-factory/fight-earnestly-ceb0eccc117f#.sshkzi23y) by PipperChip
- [The Itinerant Storyteller](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-itinerant-storyteller-54d4e6cbd9cf#.p5v9j22bl) by Joe Bloggs
- [Generating Terrain with Cellular Automata](https://medium.com/universe-factory/this-post-is-about-a-world-building-tool-ive-been-working-on-5d9560844ff5#.fdc7rjn1p) by Jasper McChesney
- [How I generated artificial rivers on imaginary continents](https://medium.com/@JLMC/how-i-generated-artificial-rivers-on-imaginary-continents-747df12c5d4c#.7201wnm13) by Jasper McChesney
- [The Sisters' War: Part 2 (Chapter 11)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-sisters-war-part-2-chapter-11-14e61b20bd3a#.hdwwftjcu) by Monica Cellio
- [The Sisters' War: Part 2 (Chapter 10)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-sisters-war-part-2-chapter-10-446d23dcbba7#.qe3cowhzj) by Monica Cellio
- [Building a truly alien alien](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-a-truly-alien-alien-f49e8230f8f2#.8j1rkelv2) by Joe Bloggs
- [When Am I? Navigation for Time Travelers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-am-i-dbc905e1ce7b#.6mk5ml2de) by Monica Cellio
- [The Sisters' War: Part 2 (Chapter 9)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-sisters-war-part-2-chapter-9-7db7b759dbfa#.yzjj2bxe5) by Monica Cellio
- [Great Lakes Earth: Wildlife](https://medium.com/universe-factory/great-lakes-earth-wildlife-2e3ea5881503#.i01wpgdka) by John Dailey
- [Want to Contribute?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/want-to-contribute-b37191c4362e#.o7009o2l6) by the community
- [The Factory Floor, Episode 1: No Pressure](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-factory-floor-episode-1-no-pressure-898a50a3571d#.57rz2o6gx)  by James
- [Prehistory of Great Lakes Earth](https://medium.com/universe-factory/prehistory-of-great-lakes-earth-6452ab393f6c) by John Dailey
- [The Sisters' War: Part 2 (Chapter 8)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-sisters-war-part-2-chapter-8-c2a73d23f1a1) by Monica Cellio
- [Biology of Fantasy: Let's Get Real, Shall We?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/biology-of-fantasy-lets-get-real-shall-we-ae5f13c2d464) by John Dailey
- [Transcendence to new world](https://medium.com/universe-factory/transcendence-to-new-world-e19560077f74) by Karan Desai
- [The Sisters' War: Part 2 (Chapter 7)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-sisters-war-part-2-6f954aef1cba) by Monica Cellio
- [The Solar System of Great Lakes Earth](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-solar-system-of-great-lakes-earth-1ac15b6c439d) by John Dailey
- [Great Lakes Earth: Geography](https://medium.com/universe-factory/great-lakes-earth-geography-372bce96d642) by John Dailey
- [Meeting the Worldbuilding Designer, Kevin Beavers](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilding-designer-b5fde86de92b) interviewed by Monica Cellio
- [Building the World of Pangaea](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-the-world-of-pangaea-d3015cd8485b) by Monica Cellio
- [Revelation for RPGs: One Last Surprise](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-even-conclusions-reveal-surprises-93a724b7e452) by Monica Cellio
- [Do Worldbuilders Play Dice?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/quantum-theory-and-albert-einstein-never-managed-to-get-along-well-f4b55c997070) by HDE 226868
- [Why Would They Do That? Discouraging Formal Education](https://medium.com/universe-factory/why-would-they-do-that-discouraging-formal-education-69c5e4fd3f7e) by Monica Cellio
- [Let It Go](https://medium.com/universe-factory/let-it-go-f63038d3d0e0) by HDE 226868
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Monty Wild](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-monty-wild-518a2d3d3ff4) by bilbo pingouin
- [Revelation for RPGs: Bringing Threads Together](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-bringing-threads-together-6a41b1905ea2) by Monica Cellio
- [Father Simon](https://medium.com/universe-factory/father-simon-e369c4eb2d55) by bilbo pingouin
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Aify](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-aify-612a1a5b084c) by bilbo pingouin
- [Recovering From Errors: Plugging Loopholes in Your Magic System](https://medium.com/universe-factory/recovering-from-errors-plugging-loopholes-in-your-magic-system-d6c60564c5f0) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Serban Tanasa](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-serban-tanasa-13438b74b8a9) by bilbo pingouin
- [Cognitive Load](https://medium.com/universe-factory/cognitive-load-6181f84e78c2) by ArtOfCode
- [Good Enough: How to Know When You're Done](https://medium.com/universe-factory/good-enough-how-to-know-when-you-re-done-7df1a16fedac) by Frostfyre
- [Revelation for RPGs: The Personal Lens](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-the-personal-lens-404b3ecc8c9e) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Dot_SpOT](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-dot-sp0t-4bf4a1654861) by bilbo pingouin
- [Nature's Oven](https://medium.com/universe-factory/nature-s-oven-eea4c8d197ad) by Tim B
- [Developing Rational Characters Through Drama Theory](https://medium.com/universe-factory/developing-rational-characters-through-drama-theory-f4db8901a07e) by Cort Ammon
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Joe Bloggs](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-joe-bloggs-91f6a0cf2eec) by bilbo pingouin
- [Cateye](https://medium.com/universe-factory/cateye-94fb2dad390f) by Frostfyre
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: DaaaahWoosh](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-daaaahwoosh-1875a52778d0) by bilbo pingouin
- [Worldbuilding for Xenoperspective](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-for-xenoperspective-a8c016d3118d) by Joe Bloggs
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: ArtOfCode](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-artofcode-5221953e8748) by bilbo pingouin
- [Worldbuilding Resources Elsewhere on Medium](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-resources-elsewhere-on-medium-df19565a91ef) by Monica Cellio
- [What do you celebrate?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-do-you-celebrate-128b3e4716ab) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Bowlturner](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-bowlturner-dbde33e9183d) by Tim B
- [What if... the Moon was another Earth?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-if-the-moon-was-another-earth-afb635c4c321) by ArtOfCode
- [Revelation for RPGs: Interactive History](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-interactive-history-d4b2ba696bdd) by Monica Cellio
- [The Travelling Salesman in Space](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-travelling-salesman-in-space-d4acc470e56b) by ArtOfCode
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: The Moderators](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-the-moderators-6fe9d7119fd1) by bilbo pingouin
- [Democracy Building in the Worldbuilding World](https://medium.com/universe-factory/democracy-building-in-the-worldbuilding-world-1a4ad92852a9) by bilbo pingouin
- [What if... the world was round?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/what-if-the-world-was-round-65df1645cc0c) by ArtOfCode
- [Worldbuilding As You Go: A Case Study](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-as-you-go-a-case-study-8d00665e3a4f) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: TrEs-2b](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-tres-2b-651a86dadd52) by Tim B
- [Editor's Picks: January 2016](https://medium.com/universe-factory/editor-s-picks-january-2016-ecd8173ce32) by ArtOfCode
- [The Lost Builder](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-lost-builder-355cf7de7ec6) by Joe Bloggs
- [Building a universe](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-a-universe-3038cecb7b06) by HDE 226868
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Tim B](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-tim-b-6c05407b4884) by bilbo pingouin
- [Deconstructing Will Hicks](https://medium.com/universe-factory/deconstructing-will-hicks-554b966960e5) by Tim B
- [Where is Will Hicks?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/where-is-will-hicks-1605c08779a9) by Tim B
- [Revelation for RPGs: Handling Transformations in Your World... and in Your Characters](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-5-handling-transformations-in-your-world-and-in-your-characters-439cf2b84f0e) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Monica Cellio](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-monica-cellio-f9a038f999ab) by Tim B
- [Networking for RPGs](https://medium.com/universe-factory/networking-for-rpg-s-b79d7ea02772) by ArtOfCode
- [Coming of Age -- Chapter 2](https://medium.com/universe-factory/coming-of-age-chapter-2-59141b5a3edc) by HDE 226868
- [The Sisters' War (Chapter 6), with author notes](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-6-with-author-notes-a2e8662228bf) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Frostfyre](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-frostfyre-ce8ee5071cb7) by Tim B
- [Making Mixtures: Creating a Balanced World](https://medium.com/universe-factory/making-mixtures-creating-a-balanced-world-1a52acf71c33) by ArtOfCode
- [Unlocking Magic Part 3: Sharing the Power](https://medium.com/universe-factory/unlocking-magic-part-3-sharing-the-power-ac4efad12617) by Cort Ammon
- [Creature Design: Santa Claus](https://medium.com/universe-factory/creature-design-santa-claus-946a9caa6e6) by Monica Cellio

### 2015

- [A new kind of sky: Living in a globular cluster](https://medium.com/universe-factory/a-new-kind-of-sky-living-in-a-globular-cluster-14e82cc33639) by HDE 226868
- [Safety First: The first lesson of Magic 101 at the Wizard's University](https://medium.com/universe-factory/safety-first-the-first-lesson-of-magic-101-at-the-wizard-s-university-cae7535034ab) by celtschk
- [Building Blocks for Worlds: Government](https://medium.com/universe-factory/building-blocks-for-worlds-government-41b90b0c55be) by Monica Cellio
- [A day on Planet Sitnikov](https://medium.com/universe-factory/binary-star-systems-are-cool-and-cooler-still-when-they-contain-planets-a111bb28b4fc) by HDE 226868
- [Revelation for RPGs: I Can See Clearly Now](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-iv-i-can-see-clearly-now-a7b84072435e) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Samuel](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-samuel-7f0887ad85c) by Tim B
- [Unlocking Magic Part 2: Under Science's Watchful Eye](https://medium.com/universe-factory/unlocking-magic-part-2-under-science-s-watchful-eye-aefebf00de13) by Cort Ammon
- [The Sisters' War (Chapter 5), with commentary](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-5-with-commentary-518cd2f51dbe) by Monica Cellio
- [Coming of Age -- Chapter 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/coming-of-age-chapter-1-63377ccbac4c) by HDE 226868
- [Electronic Angel](https://medium.com/universe-factory/electronic-angel-679039cb7381) by Tim B
- [Red Stranger](https://medium.com/universe-factory/red-stranger-8ab78489795f) by Tim B
- [Decoherence](https://medium.com/universe-factory/decoherence-969205285e4c) by Tim B
- [Revelation for RPGs: Your World Is Made of People](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-iii-your-world-is-made-of-people-467d0b5bae56) by Monica Cellio
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: HDE 226868](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-hde-226868-3763bc7705aa) by Tim B
- [Best of Worldbuilding (October)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/best-of-worldbuilding-a2fc73224b3a) by ArtOfCode
- [Unlocking Magic Part 1: Solid Foundations](https://medium.com/universe-factory/unlocking-magic-part-1-solid-foundations-313267a9db6f) by Cort Ammon
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: James](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-james-c693f062d63b) by Tim B
- [The Sisters' War (Chapter 4)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-4-e1357240d1c3) by Monica Cellio
- [Why AIs love paperclips](https://medium.com/universe-factory/why-ai-s-love-paperclips-41789855447d) by ArtOfCode
- [Dealing with Extreme Scales](https://medium.com/universe-factory/dealing-with-extreme-scales-c1540882bdb) by Cort Ammon
- [Breaking Physics](https://medium.com/universe-factory/breaking-physics-5719a2d91229) by HDE 226868
- [Meeting the Worldbuilders: Green](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilders-green-7db999b4777a) by Tim B
- [The Three Sexes Problem](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-three-sexes-problem-ef25c62363b8) by Green
- [Revelation for RPGs: The Written Word](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-2-the-written-word-45e9ef5e27ee) by Monica Cellio
- [Revelation for RPGs: Setting the Stage](https://medium.com/universe-factory/revelation-for-rpgs-ddb32bd91f20) by Monica Cellio
- [Best of Worldbuilding (September)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/best-of-worldbuilding-14729a3dac5) by ArtOfCode
- [The Sisters' War (Chapter 3)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-chapter-3-3bfaa22068b4) by Monica Cellio
- [Artificial Stupidity: Behind the Story](https://medium.com/universe-factory/artificial-stupidity-behind-the-story-fc5013a627ea) by ArtOfCode
- [Turning reality inside out, part 1](https://medium.com/universe-factory/turning-reality-inside-out-part-1-9eb226eaf84f) by HDE 226868
- [The Sisters' War (Chapter 2)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-43c4dccd1bd1) by Monica Cellio
- [Ash (Part First)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/ash-part-first-418e872c4e04) by Green
- [Creating Realistic Worlds](https://medium.com/universe-factory/creating-realistic-worlds-2406fa62a31e) by Tim B
- [Artificial Stupidity](https://medium.com/universe-factory/artificial-stupidity-5988077490ec) by ArtOfCode
- [Exploring a Binary Star](https://medium.com/universe-factory/exploring-a-binary-star-d0d1a4671cc1) by Monica Cellio
- [Conlangs for Non-linguists](https://medium.com/universe-factory/conlangs-for-non-linguists-827b1e566779) by Evan Hoffman
- [So you want to build a world... or "How to be a god"](https://medium.com/universe-factory/so-you-want-to-build-a-world-or-how-to-be-a-god-aed7304618f1) by James
- [Worldbuilding 101: On Evil Weaponry](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-101-on-evil-weaponry-b8835fb93d44) by ArtOfCode
- [Searching for a heart of...ice?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/searching-for-a-heart-of-ice-7265bf8e0206) by HDE 226868
- [Worldbuilding 101: On Suspension of Disbelief](https://medium.com/universe-factory/worldbuilding-101-on-suspension-of-disbelief-54b83fcdd6c5) by ArtOfCode
- [The eternal rebirth of Bob](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-eternal-rebirth-of-bob-a7c6952267c3) by Green
- [The Economics of Space Colonization](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-economics-of-space-colonization-46d4bc1657ca) by Serban Tanasa
- [When Cosmetic Differences Aren't](https://medium.com/universe-factory/when-cosmetic-differences-aren-t-39d058d69b47) by Monica Cellio
- [Writng Meta-Stories for Others to Use](https://medium.com/universe-factory/writing-meta-stories-for-others-to-use-46a3735d9fb5) by ArtOfCode
- [Life on Tatooine: Habitable planets in binary star systems](https://medium.com/universe-factory/life-on-tatooine-planets-in-binary-star-systems-4bee211d4dfc) by HDE 226868
- [Best of Worldbuilding (August)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/best-of-worldbuilding-cc6937034089) by ArtOfCode
- [The Sisters' War: The Story Behind the Story](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-the-story-behind-the-story-12944abf0d2a) by Monica Cellio
- [Too hot, too cold, or just right: Choosing a star for your world](https://medium.com/universe-factory/too-hot-too-cold-or-just-right-choosing-a-star-for-your-world-12190e5c2864) by HDE 226868
- [The Sisters' War (Chapter 1)](https://medium.com/universe-factory/sisters-a718622d808f) by Monica Cellio
- [How to Make a Universe on the Internet](https://medium.com/universe-factory/how-to-make-a-universe-on-the-internet-d9ebf39c7ba1) by ArtOfCode

Comment: Dang, have we really written that much? I'm impressed. And thanks for putting this together.

Comment: We've written a *bit*, yes.  (The volume is why I didn't add author names to this list -- I was already doing enough typing/cutting/pasting.  If anybody else wants to, feel free.)

Comment: What happens when this post hits the character limit? :-)

Comment: @rand al'thor Add a second post.

Comment: @randal'thor yes, as Bellerophon said, when we hit the 30,000-character limit on this post we'll just have to add another answer and divide up the entries. :-)

Comment: Going forward, we could consider dividing this list by month, especially if we plan to increase our output.

Comment: @Secespitus thanks for adding all those author credits!

Comment: @MonicaCellio No problem. I hope I got them all right with the second edit. I couldn't find/remember a username corresponding with Evan Hoffman [Conlangs for Non-Linguists](https://medium.com/universe-factory/conlangs-for-non-linguists-827b1e566779) though.