# Where can I ask about blog entries without requiring 3rd-party account?

Tags: support, blog

I have just read [The Fractal Now](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-fractal-now-110f24c97a3e#.wfb7dgi1f) after being directed to it from [a featured meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/new-blog-post-the-philosophy-behind-great-lakes-earth-and-in-case-you-missed).

Now, I have several questions about that story (eg. What is it about? How can several high-rep WB regulars see exactly what it is about? How come they do not say what is it about while praising it for capturing something perfectly? Am I overthinking it and it's just a shaggy-god-story with a trite punchline *it's about music*?), but:

- I can't ask on Medium, because it requires an account and doesn't accept SE-based one,
- I can't ask in the comments, because of reputation.

So - where should I direct those questions?

Comment: Keep in mind these are peoples creative works and I would expect that all the contributors would be happy for feedback.  That said please be conscious of how you approach providing that feedback.  Few people are happy to engage in dialogue with someone who insults their efforts.

Comment: @James Fair point. I can be really insensitive at times, even though I hate upsetting other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a lightweight account on Medium using your Google, Facebook, or Twitter account.  This is actually the same model as for SE; you don't log in to a special SE account with an SE password, but you log into whatever service is providing your credential and then sign in to SE automatically.  If you don't have, or don't want to use, any of those, you can also create an email-based account there.

Once you have created an account on Medium, you can comment on any post -- on the blog there are no reputation requirements or anything like that.  If you control the device you're connecting from (it's not a public computer), you can tell Medium to keep you logged in and you'll probably never have to think about it again, unless you use a new device or browser.  I've been signed in on my home computer since we created the blog in 2015.

If you don't want to create an account on Medium, another place you can ask questions of most<sup>1</sup> blog authors is [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), which you have enough reputation to use.  The folks in our chat room are friendly and would be happy to lend a helping hand to a new user.

For more information about contributing to the blog, including a link to Medium's help page on creating accounts, see [Want to Contribute?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/want-to-contribute-b37191c4362e#.137e4y1x7).

<sup>1</sup> The blog has attracted one contributor so far who, as far as I know, isn't an active user here on Worldbuilding.SE.  To reach Jasper you'll need to comment on Medium, most likely.

Comment: I was also going to suggest asking here on meta but chat is probably a better option.

Comment: Ah, the chat. Thank you.