# List of publications by the Worldbulding SE users

Tags: discussion

Often I read a question where the story/world behind it sounds really interesting and I want to hear/read more about it. I'm pretty sure that there are already released publications(novels, games, stories) to some of the questions answered on this site. How about creating a list where the WB SE users can link their released "product" with the questions related to it?

Comment: It seems like currently there are no publications (that we know of). Though sometimes some of us write articles in WorldBuilding's [Blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/new-blog-post-the-ambush-part-2-previous-the-juggernaut-chapter-6) on Medium where we use questions and answers from the site. If you count that as publications then you might want to read some of the stuff from that list I linked. Most of the time there is a new post every few days.