# What should I do with my World? and Where do I store it?

Tags: discussion

What should I do with this world that all of you guys have helped me build? I've thought about writing short stories, or just making it to make it. I love making it but sometimes I wonder what I can do with it. What do you guys do with your worlds? Do you use them for games, stories, tabletop campaigns? Heck, how do you guys keep track of them, how do you store them?

Comment: People are doing it for all sorts of reasons, but as you mentioned short stories I want to mention that WorldBuilding.SE has a [blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4037/28789) where short stories can be posted if you are interested. And about keeping track you might be interested in [What software is available for keeping and organising notes about your world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/499/28789)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for *what to do*, you already answered your query!  Writing stories or developing games are possibilities.  Exploring other artistic mediums such as drawing, painting, cartooning, music and poetry are also potential avenues to consider. Writing the great American fantasy novel is a common goal.  Making short Youtube episodes / movies is also a possibility.

As for how to store your information, I'd recommend the following:

- Set up an account at [Frath Wiki](http://www.frathwiki.com/).  This is a public wiki maintained for and by geopoets and language inventors.
- Join the [LCS](https://conlang.org) and take advantage of their web hosting service: create your own website or wiki for your world
- Join the [CBB](https://cbb.aveneca.com) and start up a thread devoted to your world
- Create a forum at Reddit for your stories and geopoetical lore.

Privately, I'd recommend you find a good private wiki to store your raw data. Some people use Google Docs.  I also write books of worldbuilding lore.  That's another possibility.

Make sure you have some kind of back-up plan.  Carbonite or a local manual / automatic data dump.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a plebiscite and let the denizens of my worlds vote on what happens to them after I’m done building. Some opt to become stories, others RPG campaigns. One decided to become a US Senator. It’s pretty much up to the world. I’m a benevolent deity (in that respect, anyway).