# How Do I ask Good world building Questions

Tags: discussion

Hello I just joined the stack exchange yesterday and multiple times have come across where my question was not understandable and that can sometimes be because I procrastinate and can be very lazy, if you have any ways you could help me, please share. I have never asked good questions 100% of the time and gotten my point across.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help is a good start point for many questions you have about SE worldbuilding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you are careless/lazy/a bad typist**

Make a draft outside of SE.

If your idea is new and you don't want to forget it, it is tempting to throw it directly onto Stack Exchange and then correct it afterwards.  By the time you edit it, someone will already have criticised your errors/omissions and voted to close.

Don't write your question directly into the question box on Stack Exchange; you are almost certain to make errors with the first draft. I suggest you write them first in a text editor or better, a word processor.

If you do the latter, then you can correct spelling and grammar mistakes at your leisure. You don't have to keep Stack Exchange open.

There is no hurry either. Save your your draft, leave it overnight and read it again the next day. See if it still makes sense.

Once everything is right, simply copy and paste over to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Typos are not a reason for closure. There is an edit function and edit badges for the very purpose of awarding those who put effort in fixing posts.

Comment: Typos *shouldn't* be a reason for closure, but everyone is biased. If we see that a question has a lot of typos, we're more likely to judge it harshly.

Answer (score 8):

An excellent question! And more importantly, a good *first question!*

I think your best bets will be to review the following resources:

- [The Tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [The Help Desk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help)
- [What Worldbuilding is All About](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about)
- [How to Write the Perfect Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question)
- We also have a place where you can practice writing questions: [The Sand Box](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/7184?answertab=active)

Remember that we are here to help you build your fictional world --- it could be a fantasy world, it could be a sci-fi world, it could be an alt-historical world. Whatever it may be, it should not be our actual Earth. Questions about real world physics or geography or biology or history or mathematics or theology or orbital mechanics should be addressed to the relevant Stack Exchange forums. We deal with questions about fictional physics, fictional geography, fictional biology and the like. We also deal with questions that are *rooted in* a real world domain of study (like physics, like chemistry) but require you to provide the relevant invented world context that will make them on topic here!

And lastly, don't feel like you need to rush into asking (and especially answering) queries. Take your time to learn about this forum & how it works.