# What would you have wanted to know at the beginning?

Tags: discussion

You're a seasoned worldbuilder. We're about to embark on our first build. What are some of the most crucial things you've learned that you wish you knew at the start?

Comment: Can you clarify a little? If you're just getting ready to start a project, you're not yet seasoned. If you're already seasoned, then you're not just about to start your first project!

Comment: @elemtilas i believe he isnt seasoned, and is asking for seasoned worldbuilders to share the things they wish they knew at the beginning to help him along the way. at least thats what i got out of it

Comment: Yes @Topcode is correct; that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot things it would be nice to know as a beginner. Since you're asking here, I'd point you to this basic resource:

[**What is Worldbuilding All About?**](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about)

Linked from within that response is a good selection of Resources:

[**A List of Worldbuilding Resources**](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources)