# Do atmospheric physics questions fit here?

Tags: discussion

Questions I have asked in Physics Stack Exchange were closed and I was referred to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

Does questions regarding evaporation from the oceans fit here?

I am going to ask about stability criteria for different levels of evaporation.

David

Answer (score 7):

Many SE communities point to Worldbuilding for anything that doesn't fit their scope.

However we are not the waste collector of SE: I would advise you first to read our help center together with many clarifying questions here on Meta, and then you could give it a try to our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7183/30492), again here on Worldbuilding Meta.

If you post your question there, other members will try to help you shaping it to fit the worldbuilding format, if it doesn't do so yet.

Answer (score 2):

Concur 100% with L Dutch's answer, but I do want to address a couple important ideas.

Obviously we are a worldbuilding Q&A forum. [You can find out what we're all about here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about). The long and short of it is that the answer to your specific question is both **NO** and also **YES**.

Generally speaking, real world questions don't go over well here. As L Dutch says, we are the habitual dumping ground for other Stax that for some reason don't want to deal with a question. As you describe it, I would say that your question ought to be asked in a science forum. You're asking an *informational question* on atmospheric and oceanographic matters, which, while interesting really should be asked elsewhere. (Though I will say, you can probably ask it here, and it probably won't get closed!)

That said, we dó in fact accept real world questions here, but we really need for you to give us the fictional context that your question is supposed to fit in with. The only reason I can imagine that you'd even want to ask your question here is because you plan to or are already making a fictional world! Questions of oceans and climate and atmosphere appear regularly, so you'd be in good company.

What we would need for you to do, should you decide to post the question here, is to tell us a little bit about the world you're planning. What kind of ocean are we dealing with: (is it salt water? (how saline?, what kind of star, what kind of planet, how far away, orbital period & axial tilt, etc.) or is it liquid chocolate? (dark or milk?)); what is the atmosphere like; any pertinent physical data you can provide. Also, whether the world in question is made along the lines of realism or fantasy or some other basis.