# Are questions that seek the admiration of the readers permissible?

Tags: discussion

I will admit, at times I am tempted to post questions just so that I can show off some of my creation that I think are neat, while farming reputation at the same time.

This seems like it will be a problem because it trivializes the questions themselves, making it less likely for the answers to be generalized for the use of others.

That being said, perhaps a well-contrived question can still save the post from being purely exhibitionist and creation-specific, even as a mean to an end.

Comment: As long as it's a good question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a specific problem in your world that you want help resolving, or have an interesting problem you already solved but would like to see how other people solve it, go ahead and ask it. You can then include important and relevant information about your world as part of the question. That amount of "admiration-seeking" is permissible and, indeed, expected as part of creating a good question.

If you have an interest only in sharing some unique or wondrous part of your world, then the main site is not the place to do it. The Worldbuilding SE is for Q&A, not "showing off." To do that, you could add a post to [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3667/6986) here on Meta that describes your world or you could write an article for [the blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2590/6986) that does so. The blog exists for the purpose of sharing your world, among other reasons.

Comment: I'd hold this as true, but a counter point: SE is also a catalog for future users. To that end SEs actually support asking, and then answering your own question (immediately). If you think your cool idea would be materially and probably useful to future users, it's still appropriate to post the question and answer it, or post a reality check on your idea, and allow for documentation of critique.