# What if I want to contribute only occasionally or once to the blog without joining the blog team?

Tags: discussion, blog

I have an idea for a [blog](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/we-have-a-blog?cb=1) post. The problem is, I probably won't make a bunch. Indeed, for all I know I might only be able come up with one good blog post.

How do I submit only one blog post without joining the [blog team](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/medium-blog-contributorsions)?

Answer (score 4):

> ## I'm interested in...
>
> #### Writing/contributing, either on a one-time basis or more frequently:

We are also looking for people who want to write one article. If you're one of these people, the process for contributing is broadly the same: you can either

- add yourself to the post you linked; I'll follow up on these
- drop into the [Universe Factory chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory) and talk to someone there

Either way, you'll need to create an account on [Medium](https://medium.com/), and tell one of our editors the username so that they can add you to the blog.

Comment: I didn't even read it. I'm dumb.

Comment: Just to clarify: "add you to the blog" means adding you to the list of people with permission to submit articles.  You don't need to become involved more heavily if you don't want to, but we do need to add your account to the permissions list.