# Medium Blog - Best of Worldbuilding

Tags: discussion, blog, badges

So I'm going to be writing this type of post for the blog each month - "The Best of Worldbuilding". It'll have a look at some questions and answers from the last month, and make a few awards of "badges".

What should those badges be? We can't actually award them on-site, because custom badges aren't a thing yet, but I'd like to sound out some categories. For each category, I'll award a gold, silver and bronze badge.

I'm looking for 3-4 categories with creative names (like the badges on the site) and a description of what criteria the post has to match to get it.

Comment: There is an interesting distinction that can be made here. You can either use objective criteria (like the site): highest voted question, answer, question with highest number of answers, views, etc. Or subjective like Tim B mentioned: what you found the funniest, the most challenging, where you learned the most, etc. Maybe you could clarify whether you want one or the other...?

Comment: And if you choose the latter, the title of the posts should be clarer: My best WB, the best of WB for me, etc. Just a thought.

Comment: I like the idea of using the blog to highlight specific questions (or groups of questions).  Different people will have different favorites, so maybe instead of "the" badges, each person who makes such posts should use his own?  I mean, I can totally see HDE awarding a "hardest science" badge and ArtOfCode awarding a "coolest world idea" badge and somebody else awarding a "best use of zombies" badge and so on.  Let's collect ideas here with the thought that anybody might use any of them.

Answer (score 11):

Badge Idea: **Keyboard Coffee**

A question/answer that surprised you or made you laugh so much you nearly sprayed your keyboard with your beverage of choice.

Answer (score 9):

Badge Idea: **Clickbait**

For a question title that when it made it onto the HNQ list people just had to click on it to find out what was going on...

Comment: Problem with HNQ is that it is not possible to see a posteriori who made it to it. Other than correlate with the number of views somehow.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Yeah, making it onto HNQ would not be a requirement, just a clickbait title. Generally it's easy to see what did make it on though - number of views is a solid indicator.

Answer (score 5):

**Things that make you go hmmm.** Answers that are surprisingly good but not in the expected way.  Giving an unique view to answering the question (and still being a good answer!)

Comment: I like this one, but definitely think it should only apply to answers. There are so many cases where an answer takes a stupid question and makes it awesome, I would like those answers to be honored.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I agree.  I changed it to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

I have one idea of a badge: **"World Destroyer"** - a question or an answer which aims on killing the most of people and/or destroying as much as possible.

Because, lets face it, we love building worlds. But sometimes, we love destroying them even more

Answer (score 3):

Trying to keep these searchable, all assume in the past 2 weeks/month/whatever:

**Up And Comer** - Most popular answer and/or question that's the first post by a user.

**Bad Idea Generation** - most upvoted question that was eventually closed as Idea Generation.

**Platinum Standard** - highest upvote/view ratio for a question.

**Dark Horse** - most upvoted question with <1k views (trying to exclude HNQ)

**Repapalooza** - question with the most combined upvotes, including upvotes to answers.

**Back By Popular Demand** - question with the most recent views originally asked at least two months ago.

Just some rough concepts, feel free to tweak.  Also let me know if this is too many and I can cull some.

Answer (score 1):

General idea: **Apply only one badge at a time:** From first look, I kinda liked the Gold, Silver and Bronze badge idea. But, say, who was third best in clickbaiting in last 14 days? Who let you spill third biggest amount of coffee on your keyboard?

I would assign just the "badge" itself and made it valid for certain period of time (week or 14 days)