# Why is "How can a teleporter stop a bullet?" off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question, close-reasons

[What's the safest way to catch a bullet in your body?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/111513/9182)

Was closed for being off-topic, for being "too story-based."

Why is it too story based?

Comment: The Q you link to was closed as a duplicate of your earlier question.  You significantly edited the original version which was closed (v1, edited eventually to v6) but the changes effectively invalidate answers made to v1.

Comment: @StephenG but why is it off-topic?

Comment: I changed the link such that it goes to the copy that wasn't dupe-closed and subsequently deleted. Also put some better Meta tags on this.

Comment: This question on [how to write the perfect question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) may be very useful.

Comment: just a headsup, the question in question is now in the Sandbox, if anyone wants to help the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Too story based because teleportation is not a real-world thing so without more info about your world, it would be impossible to say what teleportation can do. Weirdly, a question that is “too story based” is often fixed by giving MORE world-specific info, not less. You need to tell us how teleportation works... how fast, what happens at transition, what happens to the displaced matter at the arrival point, etc. Within that framework, the question becomes answerable. Right now, that data is all in your head, and we haven’t read your story. :-)