# My world is heavily religious. Why is it so hard to have a good question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So at first, let's talk about backgrounds of my world:

## God

In my world, God is not omnipotent. God gave up his omnipotency in spite of creating the truth values (Falsity and Truth).

He is still in charge of spiritual works though. For example, deciding whether a person must go to Heaven.

## Afterlife and stuffs

The only place of afterlife is Heaven. Hell doesn't exist. If a person/spirit is rejected from going to Heaven, they reincarnates. Possibly to a worse life.

If God thinks it's worth it, God encrowns a spirit into an angel. Angels have their missionaries, given by God.

There is no Satan/devils/demons or whatever evil supernatural beings.

## General concept of stories

Scientists were encrowned to angels. They have a variety of missions, but ultimately, they want the Reality and Heaven to unite.

## Questions I attempted to create

There are so many "questions" I had in mind, but it seems most of them can be answered myself:

- **Q:** Why would angels focus in their missions if Heaven allows them to behave freely?
- **A:** Because only people who devoted in their missionaries in their life were encrowned, and they will devote while in their afterlife, too.
- **Q:** When would God allow angels to directly impact the Reality?
- **A:** When Technological Singularity comes.
- **Q:** How would Isaac Newton, who is now Angel of Force and Embodiment of Classical Mechanics, teach Joseph-Louis Lagrange?
- **A:** Teach him when he is not even born yet.

It seems that I can have questions that focus on small details, though:

- Tentacles being also electric cables?
- I have talons that can turn into propellers. Can I fly like a plane?
- How can I breathe gravitational wave?

But still, I want to start by a question that focuses on religious stuffs. What are good examples?

## Edit 1

@JBH has a point. So here are the "rules", chronologically:

- **Modern Age:** Scientists are just encrowned to angels. The can preform "magic" in Heaven, but they cannot affect the Reality. There can be indirect effects, though. For example, Issac Newton and Joseph-Louis Lagrange above.
- **Contemporary Age:** As of Y2K, many great things happened in the Reality, such as invention of computers, aircrafts, internet, and articitial intelligences. Angels worried about them, for people who concerns about philosophical problems became fewer and fewer. Meanwhile, angels now don't rely on magic too much, and they try to solve problems with technology if possible. Spiritual works still require magic, though.
- **Future:** Technological Singularity has come, and a few angels has invaded the Reality accordingly. People in the Reality was startled by that. The Reality and Heaven haven't united though, for there are still problems in Mathematics and Physics. Magic and technology are now indistinguishable.

Comment: We host questions about gods regularly. Note that gods fall into the "magic" side of things and you can do anything you want with magic (you want talons that turn into propellers? Sure! Why not?). What we help you do is (a) develop the rules of your world and (b) consistently use them. So whether or not (e.g.) your talons can turn into propellers has more to do with "here are my rules, can this be done according to them?" than it does "can this be done?" It can always be done... but will the rules you set for yourself allow it?

Comment: Are you asking a question, or are you asking how to ask a question? If you're asking a question, this belongs in our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7183/40609) (and at the moment, it feels that way). If you're asking how to ask a question, then has your question been answered? If not, what else do you need to know about asking questions? (You might consider reviewing [How to Write the Perfect Question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/40609).)

Comment: @JBH My concern is that my world doesn't match any real-world religion. Is this really the case only I can answer my own question?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you need to correlate to a real-world religion? We host questions about fictional religions regularly. We're more than happy to help you design a fictional religion so long as you stick with Stack Exchange's one-specific-question/one-best-answer model. Just keep your questions focused on specific issues.

Comment: @JBH OK then. I'll try to find an appropriate question.

Comment: I have to say that while your world sounds curious, from the perspective of reality, if God ceases to be omnipotent, then so does all of reality as suddenly there is nothing to hold anything in existence, and even God Himself as it were would then cease to be, so you would need some other thing equal in power to God to uphold reality before God gave up His omnipotence... which is naught because God is the only equal to God.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Generally Speaking:

It's hard to come up with a good question, especially where matters of religion, the spiritual realm, theology, and so forth are concerned if you have no experience of those things in real life or don't know how to approach them as matters of study or simply because you don't quite know how they work in your fictional world. Also consider that you may already be at the stage of intuition with respect to your world that you simply don't need to ask questions! You already know the answers.

We can't really help you with the first while for the second we could refer you to one of the religion forums; but for the third we can certainly help! As in the real world, the underlying matters of Creation & cosmology& theology of a fictional world count as "fundamental aspects" or "basic systems" of that world.

Now, just from looking at your question, I can see that you've already done some rather deep thinking about your world's underlying nature. Or at the very least, you've put together some rather fascinating ideas! Just the idea of God giving up an essential part of his nature is quite interesting. Whether you've thought through to conclusions or not is well within the scope of this forum to help, and there are certainly many questions you could explore along those lines.

## As for some Specifics:

I wouldn't tag religious or theological questions as "magic" unless what you mean by magic truly does connect with divinity. They are quite different matters, though they can certainly touch on one another! Magic is almost always simply a superordinary way of manipulating the physical reality of matter and energy, and is really more closely allied with ordinary technologies than with spiritual reality. I don't know if we have a religion or theology tag or not: if we do, those would be more appropriate.

I definitely concur that we can help you develop and apply rules to your world. I think what JBH is getting at re rules is more like Laws of Nature. What are the rules your God established? If electricity is established as a Law -- the movement of electrons through a conductive medium -- then tentacles acting as power conduits seems plausible.

And you could ask that question! "Given that electricity can move through certain fibres within a living tentacle, how could this work?" You might need to clarify that the fibres are 100% biological (and thus similar to nerves) or they could be vessicular conduits (salt water tubes). You could ask follow up questions like "Based on this previous question (don't forget to link to the earlier question!), how could I connect two or more tentacles together?"

You could go back to earlier principles and ask something like "Given that God was once omnipotent, and now is not (having "given it up"); how might this affect the problem of evil?" You could also ask something like "Given that God is no longer omnipotent, has set aside a key aspect of his nature; what effect would this have on his divinity?" In other words, would such a divine being still be "God", or would his nature be so fundamentally changed that he would be no more than one of the lesser gods.