# Can you please help me focus my question better?

Tags: discussion

This thread: [Which areas of USA would have the most successful centers of growth after nuclear holocaust?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/224801/which-areas-of-usa-would-have-the-most-successful-centers-of-growth-after-nuclea)

I seem to not quite understand how to formulate my question so that it doesn't cause issues with you. I made edits but I would really like your help on this, because I don't want another question to be closed.

Comment: Seems you followed the most interesting comments (Sphennings' and Otkin's, namely). I think your question's focused enough in its current estate of state, and would try to reopen it if it did get closed :).

Comment: Your question is fine as it is now. In your scenario cities and centres of growth are nearly impossible anyway. I also do not think that you will get any good answers here (my own answer is also not so good because despite being interested in the topic I am not a specialist in this area). In the future, I would recommend doing more research on the problems you are interested in and asking more specific questions. Questions related to STEM are usually accepted better than anything else. They also tend to have better answers.

Comment: Oh man, I wanted an apocalypse not an extinction! Hahaha! But thanks for your help Otkin!

Answer (score 1):

##### Post Pockyclyptic Editing

The edit really helps tighten things up. But there are still issues. The main issues that I can see in the new edit of the query itself are really ones of topic clarity:

1. What do you mean by "success" in the setting of "turning into cities"? In other words, how are you defining these terms? Willk's response, for example, points out that a) not every city will be destroyed and b) people from hard hit areas might very well immigrate, making the already existing city even more populous. This kind of answer actually breaks your question, because it has already satisfied the requirements of your question simply by existing.
2. What do you mean by "success" in the setting of "food advantage"? I dare say that while there may not be many huge cities in the Appalachians, there are enough resources there that folks probably won't lack for food. Secondly, just because you have a city in the middle of rich farmland doesn't mean those myriads of people face a future of food security! Fresno county has about a [million people](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fresnocountycalifornia), about [4000 farms](https://www.nass.usda.gov/Publications/AgCensus/2017/Online_Resources/County_Profiles/California/cp06019.pdf), and about [70000 farmworkers](https://www.yourcentralvalley.com/news/local-news/fresno-county-unveils-agriculture-industry-covid-19-safety-guidelines/), most of whom are migrants a/o itinerant (moving from farm to farm, area to area).

There are other issues as well, that I think it would behoove you to consider!

I think in order to focus your question, you might want to think about creating 2 or 3 different questions that look at perhaps different geographical,  demographical, agricultural, and social considerations. You might also want to consider a question that deals with time frames: 10 years vs 100 years kind of thing.

21st century agriculture is extremely dependent of ultra modern science, technology and infrastructure. Seed stock, fertilisers, crop health maintenance, the plough-plant-maintain-harvest-transport cycles all depend on a variety of infrastructure systems that will be either destroyed or will suffer catastrophic failure within a few months. Without petrol, you can't run a tractor, you can't run the huge ploughs or harvesters. Without electricity, you can't run the processing plants that turn raw crops into food. Most 21st century people who live near farms have no idea how a farm actually works and have no idea how to get food from a farm if there's no Whole Foods to act as a middleman. Even those farmworkers may not know a whole lot about the big picture.

I think it's just a touch optimistic that during the ten or so years of a post apocalyptic event you'll find anything like real or sustainable city expansion. I'd suspect massive die off, surges in otherwise treatable diseases not just communicable --- note that your nuclear apocalypse coincides with the introduction of covid-19 --- but also water borne, widespread food insecurity even in the middle of an agricultural zone, and some level of deteriorisation of food production as all areas of infrastructure are debilitated.

I think cities themselves will end up being depopulated within the timeframe and where you'll likely find growth is in the latifundia that will evolve out of the old farms. If the latifundia can continue to operate a reasonably modern kind of agriculture, and if the locality can preserve and maintain the underlying infrastructure, then perhaps you might find sufficient population stabilisation and growth to consider city reinhabitation and expansion in a century or so.

You've got a fascinating thought experiment of a query, and you've clearly put some thought into it, but it's way too big for one single question! This kind of project really needs to be planned out a bit and broken down into different questions!

Answer (score 0):

**In its current form (02/27/2022 08:04am MST) I'd vote to close it again if reopened**

The Help Center states,

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

And it continues...

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally valid, there is no actual problem to be solved, you are asking an open-ended ... question.

The problem with the question is that you're looking for (a) multiple areas, (b) a subjective criteria ("most successful," what does that mean?), and you've failed to provide any limitations or criteria that would reasonably limit the responses. As written, I could legitimately answer, "my back yard" and you'd have to express a frustration *not identified in the question* to exclude it (e.g., "But your back yard can't support 10,000 people!" Well... you didn't say how many people had to be supported in your question...).

To wit, the Help Center further states that Questions...

> - Must be specific and answerable.
> - Must include context.
> - Must include restrictions/requirements.
> - Should include research.

To be fair, it's unreasonable to ask that you do research on the effects of a post-nuclear-holocaust world. But it is reasonable to expect that you've researched what people need to live, what post-explosion radiation/devastation effects would occur, etc., and that this research has led you to some *conundrum,* some problem that you've not been able to get past because there's not enough knowledge out there to achieve it through your own research. *That's the question you should be asking.* Right now, your question is indistinguishable from writer's block — we don't help people get past writer's block. From the Help Center we read,

> Questions must be specific as well as answerable. If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question.

And also...

> Search, and research: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Boiling all that down, you're expected to ask a question for which you can select a best answer based on reasonably objective conditions, not simply the attitude, "I like this one best!" You have not asked a question of that form. You have not listed conditions, restrictions, context, expectations, goals, or anything else that we need to stay reasonably on point. You haven't even defined what "most successful" means (If one community survived 50 years with zero population growth and the other the same 50 years with 10% population growth that strained it's food resources, they're both successful, which one is "most successful?"). Somehow, we need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) (for which "my back yard" can't possibly be considered a legitimate answer, if you see what I mean).

From the Help Center we learn about the [perfect question checklist](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question). That checklist doesn't reflect all of the Help Center rules I've mentioned, but it's a great place to start.

Comment: Is your backyard big enough to hold a town's population :p? Joke aside, the question reopened, I edited it to include more details on what "successful" means in the given context, existing answers and previous question the asker wrote. Take a look if you wish and decide if it still needs closure. Or ignore it, as you wish .