# Should we have a "How to write the perfect answer?" discussion?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

Sometimes, popular questions draw a large number of answers, and end up with answers that should be comments, or largely similar answers (some users prefer to write their own answers, even if they are almost identical to others, instead of helping other users to improve already posted answers).
One exemple here : [Super-robot looking for money](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48015/what-is-the-fastest-way-for-a-robot-with-superhuman-capabilities-to-make-money).

Should we have a discussion similar to [the one on question asking](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/checklist-for-the-perfect-post-idea-refinement), followed by a wiki post (like [this one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question)) ?

It could be a useful link to give to new (and old) users.

Comment: I would suggest a list of guidelines on how to answer as for a site as wide ranging as this one a one size fits all guide would be hard to produce.

Comment: @Bellerephon Each guideline could be very simple, like "Don't answer with only a link and a single sentence", or explaining that it's ok to answer "No it's impossible" as long as it's argumented, or a list of what should be said in comments instead, It could also be different specific guidelines for the most used tags.

Comment: @SpaceLizard Indeed, we have a number of such discussions here on Meta as well as on [meta.se], but it's all spread out. Maybe all that's needed, at least to begin with, is some post that brings it all together with links to the Meta posts with more details?